# Adding office.js disables html5mode

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ms-office, office-js, html5mode

I have a mean-stack website which enables `html5mode` by `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`. and `index.html` looks like as follows:

```
<html>
<head>
    <base href="/" />
    ...
</head>
<body ng-app="f">
    <ui-view ng-cloak></ui-view>
</body>
</html>
```

Because of `html5mode`, we can load in a browser, eg. `https://localhost:3000/home`, which will remain the same; without `html5mode`, that url would become `https://localhost:3000/#/home`.

Now I want the server to serve (besides the web site) also an Office add-in. I will need to be able to do `<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/addin" />` in an add-in manifest file. To this end, I need to add
`<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>` in `index.html`.

However, I realise that after adding `<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>` in `index.html` of the website, loading `https://localhost:3000/home` in a browser becomes `https://localhost:3000/#/home`, which means adding `office.js` disables `html5mode`.

Does anyone know how to what's wrong? Does anyone have a workaround?

Comment: any error in console?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow when it "becomes" the new URL. Loading Office.js shouldn't result in a redirect to a new href. Could you provide the code you're using?

Comment: Also, out of curisosity, are you triggering the dialog when a user clicks an anchor tag (aka a link or <a> tag)?

Comment: @31piy there is no meaning full error in console.

Comment: @MarcLaFleur-MSFT I rewrited my question, it is simpler now.

Comment: you should add `office.js` only when you are serving `office app`, you can use library like `oc-lazy-load` to do that

Comment: @tiona this is a good idea...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

putting comment as answer

As I understand, `office.js` is needed only for office app, in that case do not burden your web-app with office-js. Use [ocLazyLoad](https://oclazyload.readme.io/) (or some other similar library) to load the `office.js` optionally/dynamically only when needed.

Comment: `ocLazyLoad` works for me so far, though loading `office.js` for all the cases will be easier if it does not disable `html5mode`. Thank you...

Answer (score 3):

Looking at the debug version of the office.js file:

`https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.debug.js`

You'll see that the window's history replaceState and pushState functions are set to null:

```
window.history.replaceState = null;
window.history.pushState = null;
```

Which disables the ability to manipulate the browser's history and it seems it has Angular thinking the history API is not available, so Angular falls back to hashtag navigation.

You could remove these two lines of code to re-enable html5mode, but considering that the History API is most certainly disabled for a reason, **odds are that the office.js plugin will stop working properly with html5mode enabled**.

Comment: Thank you... I copied `office.js` to local, such that `https://localhost:3000/static/office.js` shows well the file. But loading `addin.html` with the new reference gave me an error in the console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :3000/static/o15apptofilemappingtable.js:1`. I always got this error no matter if I remove those two `window.history` lines...

Comment: Bringing Office.js local isn't a good solution. You should always be using the CDN version or you'll run into all sort of issues (it also won't pass validation if you're targeting the Store). 

I'm not an Angular expert, but I believe you can turn off the hashbang feature. See this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549724/angularjs-how-to-turn-off-hashbang-mode

Answer (score 3):

Modifying "office.js" itself is the wrong approach.  First of all, the Store currently requires that you reference the official Office.js CDN; so already, that approach has a problem.  Also, you don't want to be in the business of having to keep applying the same patch to a set of files that are often changing, nor to be stuck on an old version just because that's the one that you'd modified.

A much better approach is to have an additional file that *fills in* the gaps, but only as an additive thing.  It's far less invasive and less prone to breaking.

For the issue of history in particular:  see [Office.js nullifies browser history functions breaking history usage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42642863/office-js-nullifies-browser-history-functions-breaking-history-usage) for an approach that uses a polyfill to enable history.

Comment: Thank you, Michael... I just got it work with `oc-lazy-load` that @tiona suggested: so we load `office.js` for some routes and we don't load `office.js` for the others. I will try this polyfill approach if I have trouble with `oc-lazy-load`...

Comment: @SoftTimur My intention was to explain why the html5mode is disabled. I think you should accept Michael's answer, as his answer is more sound.

Comment: @ElwinArens I accepted your answer in the duplicated question and Michael's answer in another similar question. As tiona put her comment as an answer and this is what I use so far, I accepted her answer... Hope everyone is happy now...

Comment: Just tested https://github.com/devote/HTML5-History-API, adding `history.js` after `office.js` works so far...