# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'registerForEvent' of null

Tags: javascript, ms-office, office-js

In my office add-in, I launched a Dialog box:

```
var dialog;            
Office.context.ui.displayDialogAsync("https://localhost:3000/testMessages", {}, 
    function (asyncResult) {
        dialog = asyncResult.value;
        dialog.addEventHandler(Office.EventType.DialogMessageReceived, processMessage)
    })
```

`testMessages` points to a page by `angular-ui-router` in a mean stack application. I put in `views/index.html`

```
<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>
```

And in `textMessages.html`

```
testMessages
<script>
    Office.context.ui.messageParent(JSON.stringify({"req": "id", "data": "hallo"}))
</script>
```

My tests show that the message can be sent from the Dialog box to the host. However, I have got an error in the console of the Dialog box:

[image]

Does anyone know how to fix this?

**Edit 1:** I just added the following code in `views/index.js`, so that `initialize` covers the whole mean-stack application. But the error `Cannot read property 'registerForEvent'` still exists.

Additionally, I also occur [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604703/loading-office-js-adds-in-the-url).

```
<script>
    Office.initialize = function (reason) {
        $(document).ready(function () {
            angular.element(document).ready(function () {
                angular.bootstrap(document, ['myApp'])
            })
        });
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your frontend code should be in

`Office.initialize = function (reason) { ... }`

you can read more:
https://dev.office.com/reference/add-ins/shared/office.initialize

Comment: I don't know where `Office.initialize = function (reason) {}` should be put in a mean-stack application. I tried to add it inside the controller of `textMessages.html`, or in the `views/index.html`, the error message did not disappear...

Comment: We build integration using vue.js and we initialized entire app in office initialized block.  And it works as expected. Optionally you could wrap your Dialog box. But probably if you open it more then once you will get error that Office is initialized.

Comment: In general your code should be in this initialize block. But Im not saying that this is only problem in your code

Answer (score 0):

This console error will not impact dialog api functionality. And the error has already been resolved in Prod environment. Can you check what the version of the excel-web-16.00.js file is in your local ? The fixed version for excel-web-16.00.js should be 16.0.8302.1000. If your file version is not right. You can clear your cache and try again to check whether it is still exist. Thank you !

Comment: My version is `/* Excel-Online-specific API library */ /* Version: 16.0.8216.3000 */ /* Office.js Version: 16.0.8119.1000 */`. I cleared very often my browser history, this is the version I can get. So is it normal that I cannot get `16.0.8302.1000`? Is it normal that my current version has this console error?