# Can one server serve 2 angularjs modules / routings?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, express, angular-ui-router, html5mode

(I re-edited my initial question to better explain the context.)

I have a mean-stack web site built with `angular-ui-router` and `html5mode`. `routes/index.js` contains the following code, and it is `views/index.html` which has `<ui-view></ui-view>` and is the entry point of all the pages. As a result,  `https://localhost:3000/XXXX` in a browser will remain the same (rather than adding `#`) and show the corresponding content based on the router.

```
router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    console.log("router.get *");
    res.sendfile('./views/index.html');
});
```

Now, because of [this problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604703/adding-office-js-disables-html5mode), I want to have `views/addin.html` that contains `office.js` and another router, such that the site serves a set of urls `https://localhost:3000/addin/XXXX`, and I don't mind if it is `html5mode` or not (a url can contain `#` somewhere). To this end, I added one block for `addin` in `routes/index.js`:

```
router.get('/addin/*', function (req, res) {
    console.log("router.get /addin/*");
    res.sendfile('./views/addin.html')
});

router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    console.log("router.get *");
    res.sendfile('./views/index.html');
});
```

And here is `views/addin.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>addinF</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="addinF">
    addin content
    <ui-view ng-cloak></ui-view>
</body>
<script>
    var addinApp = angular.module('addinF', ['ui.router'])
    addinApp.config(['$stateProvider', function ($stateProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('addinNew', {
                url: '/addin/new',
                template: "new page"
            })
            .state('addinHome', {
                url: '/addin/home',
                template: "home page"
            })
    }]);
</script>
</html>
```

However, loading `https://localhost:3000/addin/new` or `https://localhost:3000/addin/home` just shows `addin content` and does not show `new page` or `home page` in console; it did not raise any error either.

Could anyone tell me what's missing? Can one server serve 2 angularjs modules or routings?

Answer (score 0):

Just add initial redirection:

```
appAddin.config(['$urlRouterProvider', function ($urlRouterProvider) {
    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/addin/new");
}])
```

There is a [working plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/377l9H4TN4gOykRMWDCh?p=preview)

Comment: Thank you... but `$urlRouterProvider.otherwise("/addin/new")` will redirect all the pages `https://localhost:3000/addin/XXXX` to a **same** page `https://localhost:3000/addin/XXXX#/addin/new`, I want them to be different based on router. Please see my edit of the question...

Comment: Not sure about the router.. but, simply.. what I tried to show you.. was how to trigger your initial state. We can do that with some initial redirect as well.. `appAddin.run(['$state', function ($state) {$state.go("addinNew")}])`.. there is an (example)[http://plnkr.co/edit/kf6OhXfxgbkWws1gQ2NA?p=preview]