# Adding office.js adds # in the url, then removes it

Tags: javascript, angular-ui-router, ms-office, office-js, html5mode

I have a mean-stack web site. Initially, `views/index.html` (having `<ui-view></ui-view>`) is the entry point of all the pages. It uses `angular-ui-router` and `html5mode`. Thus, `https://localhost:3000/XXXX` in a browser will remain the same (rather than adding `#`) and show the corresponding content based on the router.

Then, I want the server to serve also an Office add-in. I will need `views/addin.html` that contains `office.js` and another router, such that the site serves a set of urls `https://localhost:3000/addin/XXXX`, and I don't mind if it is `html5mode` or not (a url can contain `#` somewhere).

So here is the correpsonding of `routes/index.js`:

```
router.get('/addin/*', function (req, res) {
    console.log("router.get /addin/*");
    res.sendfile('./views/addin.html')
});

router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    console.log("router.get *");
    res.sendfile('./views/index.html');
});
```

And here is `views/addin.html`:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>F-addin</title>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.5.7/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular-ui-router/0.3.2/angular-ui-router.js"></script>
    <!--<script src="https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.js"></script>-->
    <base href="/" />
</head>
<body ng-app="addinF">
    addin content
    <ui-view ng-cloak></ui-view>
</body>
<script>
    var addinApp = angular.module('addinF', ['ui.router'])
    addinApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($stateProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $stateProvider
            .state('addinNew', {
                url: '/addin/new',
                template: "new page"
            })
            .state('addinHome', {
                url: '/addin/home',
                template: "home page"
            })
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);
</script>
</html>
```

When `office.js` is commented as above, `https://localhost:3000/addin/new` and `https://localhost:3000/addin/home` in a browser work well. However, when `office.js` is uncommented, there is an odd behavior: typing `https://localhost:3000/addin/new` in a browser will change to `https://localhost:3000/#/addin/new`, then change back to `https://localhost:3000/addin/new`. And we will see `addin content new page` appear once and disappear.

With `office.js` uncommented, if we load a manifest file with `<SourceLocation DefaultValue="https://localhost:3000/addin/new"/>`, we will see also in the task pane `addin content new page` appear once and disappear, and then `Add-in Error Something went wrong and we couldn't start this add-in. Please try again later or contact your system administrator.`

Without `html5mode` here, `.../addin/new` or `.../addin/home` in a browser will only show `addin content`; the add-in can be loaded, with only `addin content` too.

My goal is to make an add-in pointing to `.../addin/new` or `.../addin/home` work. `office.js` has to be loaded somewhere. I don't mind if it is `html5mode` (ie, the url has `#`), but the behavior in either way is odd or unsatisfactory. Does anyone know how to fix it or have a workaround?

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44604703/adding-office-js-disables-html5mode/44858254#44858254.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at the debug version of the office.js file:

`https://appsforoffice.microsoft.com/lib/1/hosted/office.debug.js`

You'll see that the window's history replaceState and pushState functions are set to null:

```
window.history.replaceState = null;
window.history.pushState = null;
```

Which disables the ability to manipulate the browser's history and it seems it has Angular thinking the history API is not available, so Angular falls back to hashtag navigation.

In the `office.js` minified version you can find these two lines by looking for:

```
window.history.replaceState=e;window.history.pushState=e;
```

You could remove these two lines of code to re-enable html5mode, but i'm not sure if the office.js plugin will keep working properly.

Comment: Thank you... I copied `office.js` to local, such that `https://localhost:3000/static/office.js` shows well the file. But loading `addin.html` with the new reference gave me an error in the console `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token < :3000/static/o15apptofilemappingtable.js:1`. I always got this error no matter if I remove those two `window.history` lines...