# Javascript redirects to the wrong URL

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I'm using angularjs and I have a very basic app...

```
let app = angular.module('GHoF', [
  'ngRoute'
]);

app.config(function Config($routeProvider) {

  // Routes

  console.log($routeProvider);
  $routeProvider
    .when('/applications', {
      templateUrl: 'app/pages/myApplications/myApplications.html',
      controller: 'MyApplicationsCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: 'app/pages/auth.html'
     })

});
```

HTML

```
<html lang="en" ng-app="GHoF">
<head>
    <script src="node_modules/angular/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.js"></script>
    <script src="app/app.js"></script>
    <title>Home</title>
</head>
<body>
    <main ng-view></main>
</body>
```

The problem is that it's redirecting me to the wrong URL.

> http://127.0.0.1:8080/#!/app/pages/auth.html

I don't know why but it appears `/#!` in the URL. This is a very basic app...

Comment: because you have it set up to use hashbang

Comment: What do you mean? I didn't configure anything else beside what I have

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26549724/angularjs-how-to-turn-off-hashbang-mode

Comment: it works... thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable `HTML5Mode` to get rid of the hashbangs. First you need to add the base href in your index file (I usually put this directly under the opening `<head>` tag):

```
<base href="/">
```

Then in your config, you should enable it via the $locationProvider:

```
app.config(function Config($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
  $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
  $routeProvider
    .when('/applications', {
      templateUrl: '/app/pages/myApplications/myApplications.html',
      controller: 'MyApplicationsCtrl'
    })
    .otherwise({
      redirectTo: '/app/pages/auth.html'
    })
});
```

---

Don't forget you will want to handle server rewrites if you plan on going directly to those routes in HTML5 mode.

This is a good resource for information on how to do that for different servers: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Comment: it works but it's not redirecting now...

Comment: I think `redirectTo: 'app/pages/auth.html'` needs a leading slash to redirect from the root. Try `redirectTo: '/app/pages/auth.html'` or even `redirectTo: '/pages/auth.html'` if /app is already your root

Comment: it doesn't redirect... I go to `http://127.0.0.1:8080/applications` and says `Cannot GET /applications`

Comment: If you're going directly to that URL, you need to add rewrites to your server. See: https://riptutorial.com/angularjs/example/21798/things-to-do-when-using-html5mode

Comment: @user12361681I updated my answer with a better link in case you're not using apache