# Javascript stop browser advertisement add ons

Tags: javascript, angularjs, browser-addons

Is there any way to stop browser add-ons from injecting HTML code?

I am having a website built in angularjs but because of some browser add-ons my route is getting messed up, this is the HTML snippet which is causing some errors in my angularjs:

```
<script async="" src="http://b.scorecardresearch.com/beacon.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" async="" src="http://in1.perfectnavigator.com/d.php?id=57573&amp;eid=&amp;vdisp=0&amp;u=http://www.domain.com/app/#/users&amp;r=http://www.domain.com/site/profile/view/&amp;vdisplayEn=0&amp;vsliderEn=1&amp;bannerAds=1&amp;usadservEx=Oj45JDs7PTUiNg&amp;lrc=0&amp;curatedSite=0"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://api.jollywallet.com/affiliate/client?dist=111&amp;sub=1&amp;name=Browser%20Extensions"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://colo.cachefly.net/js/min.inject.js?id=Pz8sOCA"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://colo.cachefly.net/js/min.inject.js?id=Pz8sOis"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://colo.cachefly.net/js/min.inject.js?id=Pz8sOiA"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://colo.cachefly.net/js/min.inject.js?id=Pz8sOSA"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://colo.cachefly.net/js/min.inject.js?id=Pz8sOSs"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_main.jsp?dlsource=hhnkdzlc&amp;CTID=ssaddon"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://istatic.datafastguru.info/fo/min/abc1RSQC.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://i.swebdpjs.info/sweb/javascript.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cond01.etbxml.com/conduit_bundle/web/hotels.php?mamId=G8K2&amp;userId=2222&amp;appId=3333&amp;&amp;ui=1&amp;ns=ETB_Hotels_Widget&amp;partner=smg"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://cdn.visadd.com/script/14567725590/preload.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.tr553.com/InterYield/bindevent.do?e=click&amp;affiliate=harel777&amp;subid=iy&amp;ecpm=0&amp;debug=false&amp;snoozeMinutes=1&amp;adCountIntervalHours=24&amp;maxAdCountsPerInterval=6&amp;endpoint=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.tr553.com"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://intext.nav-links.com/js/intext.js?afid=wolfpack&amp;subid=def&amp;maxlinks=4&amp;linkcolor=006bff&amp;wiki=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.adcash.com/script/java.php?option=rotateur&amp;r=234715"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" id="jw_00" src="//d2cnb4m0nke2lh.cloudfront.net/jollywallet/resources/js/2/affiliate_client.js"></script>
<script src="//jsgnr.datafastguru.info/fl/blm"></script>
<script src="//jsgnr.datafastguru.info/site-classification"></script>
<script src="//jsgnr.datafastguru.info/fl/blm"></script>
<script src="//jsgnr.datafastguru.info/bwl/wl"></script>
<script src="//jsgnr.datafastguru.info/fl/blm"></script>
<script src="//pstatic.datafastguru.info/fo/ecom/lang.js?c=in"></script>
<script src="//pstatic.datafastguru.info/rss/min/fo.min.js?v=2_3_621&amp;b=dynamic&amp;l=right"></script>
<script src="//jsgnr.datafastguru.info/bwl/wl?v=1"></script>
<script src="//jsgnr.datafastguru.info/site-classification"></script>
<script src="//pstatic.datafastguru.info/fo/ecom/lang.js?c=in"></script>
<script src="//jsgnr.datafastguru.info/bwl/wl?v=1"></script>
<script src="//pstatic.datafastguru.info/rb/min/fo.min.js?v=1_1_63"></script>
<script src="//jsgnr.datafastguru.info/bwl/bl"></script>
<script src="//jsgnr.datafastguru.info/bwl/bl?v=1"></script>
<script src="//jsgnr.datafastguru.info/bwl/bl?v=1"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.superfish.com/ws/sf_preloader.jsp?dlsource=hhnkdzlc&amp;CTID=ssaddon&amp;ver=2014.11.25.14.48"></script>
```

Because of this my URL which was:

`www.domain.com/app/#/users`

changes to

`www.domain.com/users`

And I am getting URL related errors: `TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined`

If I run my website on a browser without any add-ons it works like a charm, but with the above add-ons I am getting errors.

One of our websites user's is facing this issue. Is there any solution to get rid of this?

Comment: Is this throughout your website - like an advertiser for your website is adding them in, or is just some particular user who has way too many spam addons in their browser?

Comment: So some users of website are having add ons and there browser is injecting these code

Comment: If `#` is a directory name, make a symlink/hardlink and use that in urls, so that it doesn't accidentally get treated as a target.... Can you cut out the unnecessary tags for readability?

Comment: `#` is not a folder, its the HASH url used by angularjs.

Comment: I don't think that `#` is valid. Try changing the directory name.

Comment: I guess you'd need to figure out the specific add on that is causing your routes to break. That way you'll know better what's happening and why it is. Do you know what particular add on is causing this?

Comment: have you thought about using AngularJS without hash? at least with this specific client? i.e. turn on/off this feature by something like a query string. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash

Comment: simple and cheap solution: tell user to launch an incognito window to use your app if they have lots of crapware.

Comment: I think problem may be due to browser addons. Use adwcleaner to remove adwares from browsers.

Comment: Do you know if the add-on is modifying the URL directly, or injecting the above `<script>` tags into your page which then modify the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I looked a bit into intercepting the `<script>` element injection into the document and prevent loading the code. Disclaimer: I'm no expert on this subject, I just wanted to share what I tried.

At first, I played a bit with [`MutationObserver`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), watching the DOM for the creation of a `<script>` element, and removing it. I came up with the following snippet, added at the very beginning of my HTML page, supposedly to make it load first:

```
// Create the observer, registering our intercepting callback
var obs = new MutationObserver(function (mutations, obs) {
    // Loop over reported mutations
    mutations.forEach(function (mutation) {
        // childList means nodes have been added. That's the only thing
        // we're interested in
        if (mutation.type !== 'childList') return;

        // Check the added nodes
        for (var i=0; i < mutation.addedNodes.length; i++) {
            var node = mutation.addedNodes[i];
            // Ignore all but SCRIPT elements
            if (node.nodeName !== 'SCRIPT') return;
            // Remove it
            node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
            console.log(node.nodeName);
        }
    });
});
// Start observer
obs.observe(document, {subtree: true, childList: true});
```

Obviously, this was doomed to fail. If I need to ask a parent element to remove the node, that means it was already added to the DOM and loaded (loading, at least) when I came in to prevent it.

I tried to get there earlier, by overriding [`document.createElement`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.createElement) and returning `<div>`s instead of `<script>`s:

```
document.createElementOriginal = document.createElement;
document.createElement = function (tagName) {
    if (tagName.toLowerCase() == 'script') {
        console.log('Script interception');
        tagName = 'div';
    }

    return document.createElementOriginal(tagName);
};
```

But no luck. Looking at the console, no interception was reported. Still too late.

I can only conclude that the extension data is injected before any script on my page is executed, or that the element injection is made in an way independent of the scope I could access in my code.

If you have any suggestion in how I could investigate further, feel free to point me in that direction.

Answer (score 1):

Tell the user to uninstall her add-ons.

OR, if you are truly intent on making your website compatible with this user's array of add-ons (perhaps she is a person of high importance, or she represents many people in an organization in which everyone has these add-ons installed?)...

Designate the line of code at which the error is thrown, and set a breakpoint there. [Here are instructions on how to do that in Chrome.](https://developer.chrome.com/devtools/docs/javascript-debugging) Walk your way up the call stack and see if you can find any clues.

If that does not work, try removing some of those scripts. Find out which ones, when removed, solve the issue. Try as many combinations as you are willing to try. Once you have found the culprit script, determine which add-on injected it. Instruct the user to uninstall this add-on, otherwise she will not be able to use your website.

If you want to work around the existence of this script, and you really think it's worth your time (it probably isn't), you can examine the culprit script and try to find out where it's screwing you up. If the script is minified, you can drop it into a deobfuscator like [jsnice](http://www.jsnice.org/) and scour it. Of course, that will take forever.

In a final bid to get your site to work alongside these add-ons, you could employ various hacks, like wrapping your code in `try catch` blocks and redirecting on errors, using `setTimeout` to sidestep errors, etc etc... but really, the easy and obvious solution is to uninstall the add-ons.

Comment: I don't want to invest time in coding entire angularjs from where problems are getting triggered. For now I have implemented error interceptor and looking for error exactly like `TypeError: Cannot read property 'charAt' of undefined` and prompting user to uninstall the addons, but thats just the hack. I am sure there are many web developers who are frustrated with these addons, so is there any proper way to do it.

Comment: The "proper" fix will require a lot of work to figure out, probably involving some of the steps I laid out for you above. You don't want to set any breakpoints in your code; neither would I. You may very well never figure out the fix. The only way to win is to not play.

Comment: I don't understand the downvote. This is a perfectly valid answer, and quite complete if you ask me. +1

Answer (score 1):

You can not disable addons but you can overwrite their functionality. as every javascript code runs under window context, you will get access to addons variable. You just need to do some RnD on those add ons and replace functions before your script loads.

Comment: Addons are executed before any JS on the page is executed. So even if you overwrite the addon method it will be too late.

Answer (score 1):

If an addon messes with a website's URL, it's going to break the website. This is not the fault of you, the website developer, but instead the fault of the addon developer (assuming you did not install these "addons" into your website yourself). I feel like there's some sort of miscommunication or something missing if the "addon" is changing your url from a hash to an html5mode pushstate url.

Have the user figure out WHICH addon is causing the bug by one by one having her disabling every addon until the problem goes away. With the information you provided there's absolutely not enough information to go on and I would generally advocate to close this question on that basis.

Once you identify the addon in question, contact their developer asking them why they are changing the URL of random websites.

If the user has an addon that converts www.google.com to www.giggle.com would you not expect the website to "break"? You can't expect google to fix this behavior.