# In angularJs, play framework, after refresh(F5) ng-view is not working

Tags: angularjs, playframework, routes, ng-view

I'm making homepage, and there is such a troublesome thing.

localhost:9000/ this url is my main page.

And there are three categories, a,b,c on the top of homepage.

When I clicked a, url will be changed localhost:9000/a

I can see partial view that shows one sentence "hello world!". It's working well.

But when I hit refresh(F5), view shows {{sentence}}.

I think that the reason why I can't see the correct view is that a.html can't load resources.

Only main.html have a whole html structure. And other html doesn't have.

a.html have only

## {{sentence}}

.

below is small code block in javascript.

```
myApp.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider' ,function($routeProvider,$locationProvider){
    $routeProvider
        .when('/a',{
            templateUrl:'a',
            controller:'aCtrl'
....
}
myApp.controller('aCtrl',['$scope',function($scope){
    $scope.message = "hello world!";
}]);
```

It's routes

```
GET        /               controllers.Application.index
GET        /a              controllers.Application.a
```

It's Application.java

```
package controllers;

import play.*;
import play.mvc.*;

import views.html.*;

public class Application extends Controller {

    public static Result index() {
        return ok(index.render("Your new application is ready."));
    }

    public static Result a(){ return ok(a.render());}
}
```

So is there any solution?? I really can't find the solution.

Or is it normal in angularJs? cause it's single page app.

Only main page can use refresh(F5). It shows right view.

Please Help me!!!!!!! OTL

Comment: Show us your problematic code.

Comment: Check your browser console for js errors.

Comment: I checked browser console... and there are no errors.

Answer (score 0):

The Play Framework and AngularJS both have a routing system, which don't match well in your example.

As there is several options to match them, let's suppose you only want to rely on the AngularJS routing system, and want large browser compatibility (see [AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash) ).

**conf/routes** : you catch all the URL to a same controller

```
GET     /$id<[a-c]?>                controllers.Application.index(id: String)
GET     /assets/*file               controllers.Assets.at(path="/public", file)
```

**Application.scala** : the index function add a # symbol on non-root URL, in order to trigger route change on the side of AngularJS

```
package controllers
import play.api._
import play.api.mvc._

object Application extends Controller {
  def index(id: String) = Action {
    if (id.nonEmpty) {
      Redirect("/#/"+id)
    } else {
      Ok(views.html.main("Hello"))
    }
  }
}
```

On the AngularJS side, you probably don't have to make change, cause AngularJS change route as needed in your description. For reference, this is a working example :

**main.js**

```
var app=angular.module('main', ['ngRoute']);
app.config(function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.when('/a',        {templateUrl: '../assets/tpl/a.html', controller: 'a'});
    $routeProvider.when('/b',        {templateUrl: '../assets/tpl/b.html', controller: 'b'});
    $routeProvider.otherwise(        {templateUrl: '../assets/tpl/default.html', controller: 'default'});
});
app.controller('default', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    console.log('default controller');
});
app.controller('a', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    console.log('controller a');
});
app.controller('b', function($scope, $http, $location) {
    console.log('controller b');
});
```