# Angular + Laravel : loading view via ngRoute

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs, laravel, ng-view

I'm facing this problem when combining Laravel and Angular:

Following a very simple [tutorial](http://justinvoelkel.me/laravel-angularjs-part-two-login-and-authentication/) I found online, I was trying to load a view using the `ng-view` directive. However, I am unable to actually *load* the template. This is my `app.js` code:

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module('profuApp', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/inicio', {
                templateUrl: '../templates/inicio.html',
                controller: 'homeCtrl'
            })
            .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
    }]);

    app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
        $http.get('http://localhost:8888/profucom/public/getData').success(function(data) {
            $scope.datos = data;
        });
    }])

})();
```

My file tree:

```
app/
bootsrap/
public/
   js/
      angular.min.js
      angular-route.min.js
      app.js
   templates/
      inicio.html
. . .
```

The site loads normally, but when I watch the source code, instead of watching the template inside of `inicio.html`, this happens...

**Code with within my index.blade.php file**

```
<div ng-view></div>
```

**Code I see in the browswer's source code**

```
<!-- ng-view: -->
```

The `network` tab on Chrome does not show a 404 error trying to load the view.

What I've tried so far:

1. Placing templates inside the `js` folder (templateUrl: 'templates/inicio.html')
2. Placing templates inside the `public` folder (templateUrl: '../templates/inicio.html')

   - also, `templateUrl: '/public/templates/inicio.html'`
3. Placing templates inside the root folder (templateUrl: '/templates/inicio.html')
4. Placing just the file inside the `js` folder: (templateUrl: 'inicio.html')

None of the above seem to work. Any help, please?

**EDIT** I also see this happenning in the url: instead of `myapp/public/inicio` it loads like `myapp/public/inicio#/`

Comment: I believe it's because your base href is off. GO to your network tab, what is the path it's attempting to include?

Comment: That's the thing, it is not even calling it. There is no 404 error because there IS no call to it. I edited he question to report another unknown behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once again, it was nothing but a human mistake. I'm sorry and thankful at the same time for those who spent time trying to answer and comprehend my problem. This is the solution:

I was using the latest stable version directly from a CDN, version **1.3.5**; however - and just to see what'd happen - I changed to version **1.2.28**. *What's the difference?* A little syntax.

Instead of what I did above...

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
. . .
```

I did this:

```
app.controller('homeCtrl', function($scope, $http) { 
. . .
```

Changing from one version to another was the answer, and changing a little the syntax.

I hope this helps anyone as distracted as I was.

Answer (score 0):

Where is your index.blade.php located? `templateUrl` should be the path to the template from whatever file loads the app.js code (I'm assuming that's index.blade.php). So if that's in the root directory, `templateUrl: '/public/templates/inicio.html'`

As for the issue with the `#`, read [this somewhat related question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)

Comment: My index.blade.php is in folder `app/views/`. I tried that very same route you provided but the problem persists.

Comment: What URL are you testing this on? localhost/8888/inicio or localhost/8888/#/inicio ?
Do you have multiple angular modules in this one app? I'm a little confused about the `myapp/public/inicio` vs `myapp/public/inicio#/` discrepancy—where exactly is that url from/located?

Comment: I'm testing on localhost:8888/myapp/public/inicio. Only one module, the one on app.js

Comment: Hm, it could be that somewhere on your server you are serving up incorrect files. I don't know how you have it set up, but are you always pointing to the index.blade.php file, regardless of the route? What happens when you try localhost:8888/#/myapp/public/inicio?
See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16569841/angularjs-html5-mode-reloading-the-page-gives-wrong-get-request) for more details.