# AngularJS routing to partials on OS X

Tags: javascript, angularjs, apache, .htaccess

So, I'm writing an AngularJS application. Everything works great on my production web server. Though routing works for my app on my localhost (dev server) but only when I navigate to my index.html first. If I try to go to a partial on my dev server, it does not work and I get a 404

**localhost/myapp/about.html**
    Not Found

```
The requested URL /myapp/about.html was not found on this server.
```

**Console**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found)
```

This is the **.htaccess** I am using for my dev server:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymlinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase /~yourusername/appname/public/
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !.*\.(css|js|html|png|jpg|jpeg|gif|txt)
    RewriteRule (.*) index.html [L]
</IfModule>
```

I found the above .htaccess from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash#answer-21484874). This is different than the .htaccess I am using from my production server. The reason being is because if I tried using the same .htaccess as my production server, I get the following:

**localhost/myapp/about.html**

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /index.html on this server.
```

**Console**

```
Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403 (Forbidden)
```

**.htaccess** for production server

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]

RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.html [NC,L]
```

I know this can't be right as I have checked all my permissions (and setup a rule to ensure correct permissions) and my settings in httpd.conf. I have no idea which way to go in terms of which .htaccess file I should use. I think I should use the first one but don't get why the second one doesn't work as both servers have the same httpd.conf (and apache2.conf) and the same permissions and same groups. Both my index.html and app.js are the same for both production and dev servers.

For reference I'll post below my index.html and my app.js

**index.html**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="app" ng-controller="AppController">

<head>
    <title>{{ Page.title() }}</title>
```

...

```
    <base href="/app/" target="_self" />
    ...

    <script src="app/application.js"></script>
    <script src="app/directives/site-templates.js"></script>
    <script src="app/controllers.js"></script>
    <script src="app/factories.js"></script>

</head>


<body id="page">
<div id="container">
    <site-header id="header"></site-header><!-- End header container -->

    <div id="view" class="container"ng-view></div><!-- End view container -->

    <site-footer id="footer"></site-footer><!-- End footer container -->
```

...

**app.js**

```
 var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute', 'ui.bootstrap', 'site-templates']); 

app.config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider, $httpProvider){ 
    $routeProvider 
    // Home 
    .when('/', {
        redirectTo: '/index.html'
    })
    .when('/index.html', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/home.html',
        controller: 'AppController'
    })
    //Contact me
    .when('/contact.html', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/contact.html', 
        controller: 'ContactMeController'
    })
    //About me
    .when('/about.html', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/about.html', 
        controller: 'AboutMeController'
    })
    // else 404 
    .otherwise('/404.html', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/404.html', 
        controller: 'PageController'
    }); 

    $locationProvider

    .html5Mode(true);
});
```

**EDIT/UPDATE**: It works when I use localhost/myapp/#/contact.html but does not work when I do localhost/myapp/contact.html.

Comment: according to your routes, you should be going to `localhost/myapp/#/about.html`, not `localhost/myapp/about.html` You are getting a 404 because `localhost/myapp/about.html` doesn't exist. It looks like it'd be `localhost/myapp/partials/about.html`

Comment: Awesome, so `localhost/myapp/#/about.html` works but why doesn't it work without the #? I though I got rid of that with `$locationProvider.html5mode(true);`

Comment: I think you're looking for `$locationProvider.html5Mode(false);`, not `true` I haven't played around much with that setting

Comment: But if I add false, then I have to have my `.when('#/about.html', { ...});` I want cleaner looking url schema.

Comment: ahh ok, maybe its a problem with your base href path. Sorry, I'm new to this html5 mode thing. Never really looked into it

Comment: Nah, you're cool man. I am just trying to get it to work. You pointed me in the right direction. I was thinking it was permissions but you've proved that it isn't.

Comment: So with the base href on my production server, I had to get rid of my base href and on my dev side, it gives me the error $location:nobase if I get rid of the base href. Oh and I had to do $locationProvider.html5mode({ enabled: true, requireBase: false}); on my server's app.js... my bad. Though I still haven't figure it out on my dev server.