# Tabs with angularjs routing and jquery

Tags: jquery, html, angularjs, angularjs-routing

I added routing to my project but now I have a problem with my tabs on a page I redirect to them using the id. But now when using routing it thinks I want to redirect to a page when one of the tabs is clicked. I also use jQuery for animation.

Here is the HTML

```
   <div class="tabs">
        <ul class="tab-links" style="margin-bottom: 0px;margin-left: 5px;">
            <li ng-class="{active : prefferdFuel == 'Diesel'}"><a ng-show="fuelPrice.DIESEL != null"href="#Diesel">Diesel</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active : prefferdFuel == 'Eurosuper'}"><a href="#Eurosuper" ng-show="fuelPrice.EUROSUP != null">Eurosuper</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active : prefferdFuel == 'Super98'}"><a href="#Super98" ng-show="fuelPrice.SUPER98 != null">Super 98</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active : prefferdFuel == 'CNG'}"><a href="#CNG" ng-show="fuelPrice.CNG != null">CNG</a></li>
            <li ng-class="{active : prefferdFuel == 'ADBlue'}"><a href="#ADBlue" ng-show="fuelPrice.ADBLUE != null">AD Blue</a></li>
        </ul>
        <div class="tab-content">
            <div id="Diesel"  ng-class="prefferdFuel == 'Diesel'? 'tab active' : 'tab'">
                <p>Diesel &#8364; {{fuelPrice.DIESEL}}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Eurosuper" ng-class="prefferdFuel == 'Eurosuper'? 'tab active' :'tab'">
                <p>EuroSup &#8364; {{fuelPrice.EUROSUP}}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="Super98" ng-class="prefferdFuel == 'Super98'? 'tab active' :'tab'">
                <p>Super+98 &#8364; {{fuelPrice.SUPER98}}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="CNG" ng-class="prefferdFuel == 'CNG' ? 'tab active' :'tab'">
                <p> CNG &#8364; {{fuelPrice.CNG}}</p>
            </div>
            <div id="ADBlue" ng-class="prefferdFuel == 'ADBlue'? 'tab active' : 'tab'">
                <p> AD Blue &#8364; {{fuelPrice.ADBLUE}}</p>
            </div>
        </div>
```

this is the JQuery

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery('.tabs .tab-links a').on('click', function(e)  {
        var currentAttrValue = jQuery(this).attr('href');
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).siblings().slideUp(400);
        jQuery('.tabs ' + currentAttrValue).delay(400).slideDown(400);
        jQuery(this).parent('li').addClass('active').siblings().removeClass('active');

        e.preventDefault();
    });

});
```

I also need to add I'm using angular ui router. is there a way to fix this?

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use urls with hashtags since angular uses the hashtag as a prefix (you can disable it though), see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash/14320468#14320468) in SO for more info about it

Comment: i tried the solution of that question but it still doesn't work. it worked perfectly without the routing but now it wont work. also thanks for the quick reply :)

Answer (score 0):

If you decide to add in angular routing into your project, then you will run into issues with JqueryUi Tabs because the href with the # tag will trigger a route change in Angular. I wrote up a concept on how to get around this

```
    function jqueryTabs () {
    return {
        $container: [],
        $list: [],
        link: function (scope, element, attrs) {
            var _self = this;
            setTimeout(function () {
                _self.$container = $(element[0]);
                _self.$list = _self.$container.find('ul:first-child');
                _self.init();
            }, 200);
        },
        init: function () {
            var _self = this;

            this.$container.addClass('ui-tabs ui-widget ui-widget-content ui-corner-all');
            this.$list.addClass('ui-tabs-nav ui-helper-reset ui-helper-clearfix ui-widget-header ui-corner-all');

            var $bodyItems = this.$container.children('div');
            $bodyItems.addClass('ui-tabs-panel ui-widget-content ui-corner-bottom');

            var $listItems = this.$list.children('li');
            $listItems.addClass('ui-state-default ui-corner-top ui-tabs-active');

            var $listAnchors = $listItems.children('a');
            $listAnchors.addClass('ui-tabs-anchor');
            $listAnchors.css('cursor', 'pointer');
            $listAnchors.on('click', function () {
                _self.tabClicked($(this));
            });

            var $firstAnchor = $listItems.children('a').first();
            $firstAnchor.trigger('click');
        },
        tabClicked: function ($element) {
            var targetId = $element.data('target');
            var $target = this.$container.find(targetId);
            var $parent = $element.parent();

            $parent.addClass('ui-state-active').siblings('li').removeClass('ui-state-active');
            $target.css('display', 'block').siblings('div').css('display', 'none');
        }
    };
};
```

So that will be your directive that you will register with angular.

```
app.directive('jqueryTabs', jqueryTabs);
```

And all you gotta do in your div is include the reference to the directive

```
<div class="tabs" jquery-tabs>
```

The anchor tag in each tab will also need to be altered slightly. So remove the href and replace it with data-target like so:

```
<a ng-show="fuelPrice.DIESEL != null" data-target="#Diesel">Diesel</a>
```

You may need to tweak the js slightly for the container div you have in there but I tested this out and it seems to work fine with me. Hope this helps!