# Angular ngRoute - Cannot GET page if enter url manually

Tags: angularjs, ngroute

I'm a beginner to AngularJS and have the following question. I'm playing with ngRoute module and this is my code so far:

**html:**

```
<nav ng-controller="navController as nav">
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="item in navItems">
            <a href="{{ item.url }}">{{ item.name }}</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav>


<div id="main">
    <div ng-view></div>
</div>
```

**app.js**

```
(function(window) {

    var app = angular.module('app', ['ngRoute']);

    app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
            .when('/', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/home.html',
                controller  : 'mainController'
            })
            .when('/contact', {
                templateUrl : 'pages/contact.html',
                controller  : 'contactController'
            });

        if (window.history && window.history.pushState) {
            $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
        }
    }]);


    app.controller('mainController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Hello from home page';
    }]);


    app.controller('contactController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.message = 'Hello from contact page';
    }]);

    app.controller('navController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
        $scope.navItems = [
            { name: 'Home', url: '/' },
            { name: 'Contact', url: '/contact' }
        ];
    }]);

})(window);
```

And it works fine. Angular renders menu, and when I click on the link it shows me desired page. But except in the following case. When it displays the homepage (url: http://localhost:3000) and i manually add to the url address "/contact" then I'm getting blank page with error "Cannot GET /contact". Could someone explain me why this is happening and how can I fix it? I would appreciate any help. Thanks.

Comment: try to add #/contact

Comment: You mean to the url? Yes, then it works. But user probably won't type #/contact ;] Most likely I should not bother about it at all, but I'm curious if there's fix for it.

Comment: Y did u want to be typed manually??

Comment: <base href="/"> have you included this at your <head> tag as you are using html5mode?

Comment: Yes, i have base tag in my <head>

Comment: @covfefe did you ever find a solution to this? I know this is super old haha. If I type `localhost:3000/#/about` it works and changes back to `localhost:3000/about`, but I'd like `localhost:3000/about` to just work

Answer (score -1):

In fact you need the # (hashtag) for non HTML5 browsers.

Otherwise they will just do an HTTP call to the server at the mentioned href. The # is an old browser shortcircuit which doesn't fire the request, which allows many js frameworks to build their own clientside rerouting on top of that.

You can use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) to tell angular to use HTML5 strategy if available.

Here the list of browser that support HTML5 strategy: http://caniuse.com/#feat=history

Source: [AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)