# Link to "/" works in some browsers only

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing

This link does not work in all browsers in my angularjs onepage app.

```
<a href="/">homepage</a>
```

Depending on the browser the url becomes different. In some browser the url ends with a trailing "/#" and others with "/#/" e.g. "http://localhost/#" and "http://localhost/#/". This means that in non IE browsers request ending with /# fails to load ViewA

This is my route provider:

```
mainApp.config(["$routeProvider",
function ($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "Views/ViewA.html"
        })
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl: "Views/ViewB.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
}]);
```

Is there a way to make the browsers behave the same? A library to reference?
My only references er:
angular.js
angular-route.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you to take a look at the answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting)

It basically depends on the angular routing mode you want to use:

- Hashbang Mode;
- HTML5 Mode;
- Hashbang in HTML5 Mode

Answer (score 1):

I'd say your anchor should be:

```
<a href="/#/">homepage</a>
```

Comment: yes, that would work, but that's not what I meant. Is there a way to get the url "/" to work in all browsers?

Comment: By default the # is necessary. That depends whether you want to support non-HTML5 browsers. See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash

Answer (score 0):

Adding a locationProvider with html5mode set to true, seems to solve my issues

```
mainApp.config(["$locationProvider", "$routeProvider",
function ($locationProvider, $routeProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "Views/ViewA.html"
        })
        .when("/home", {
            templateUrl: "Views/ViewB.html"
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/"
        });
}]);
```