# Extract data from current URL and use it in ajax call as a paramenter

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, ajax, url

I am developing a website in which only 1 html page is there in which I first fethch the url & gets the id from url and send it to api using ajax call. On success, I displays data of the given id from url.My code is as-

```
 <script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $('#main').hide();

            var url = window.location.href;
            var formno = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/') + 1);

            if (formno != 'Login.html') {              
                var apiUrl = 'http://localhost:801/api/api/Patient/Get';    
                $.ajax({
                    url: apiUrl,
                    crossDomain: true,
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    type: 'GET',
                    data: { formNo: formno },
                    success: function (result) {                           
                        $('#main').show();
                        alert("Success" + result)
                    },
                    error: function (result) {
                        alert("error :: " + JSON.stringify(result))
                    }
                });    
            }    
        });      
    </script>
```

when I use the url as `abc.in#1` it displays the success alert but I want to give the url in format `abc.in/1` at that time it gives

```
HTTP Error 404.0 - Not Found
The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.
```

Why it can not find the page? Is there any solution for this?
I want to give plain url as `abc.in/1` where 1 is `id` and which is dynamic.
Is there any solution?

Comment: if you end the url with `/1` then your web server will be looking for a sub folder named `1`.  The first implementation you have, using hashes, is perfectly normal and quite frankly a simpler approach.  It means you stay on the same page all the time, whereas your approach means jumping from page to page and handling pages that don't exist.

Comment: abc.in/1  is requesting a page called "1", which does not exist.  You probably want to use a query string like, abc.html?id=1 and then capture the parameter. See this post: [How can I get query string values in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Your browser is probably trying to access document on location abc.in/1, which doesn't exist. You will need some server side logic for this, e.g. php router which will always serve your document, and additonal parameters will be processed by it. abc.in#1 anchor is different type of url parameter, which purpose is to be processed by document or javascript on client side.

Comment: That will involve a page load though, and the questioner states they want to use AJAX to load all pages, into the one page.