# angularjs ngroute and htaccess rewrite

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, url, mod-rewrite, ngroute

I am wondering how to work angularjs ngRoute and htaccess rewrite together.

I have ngRoute working so I get URLs like these:

```
http://domain.com/#/something/somestring
```

But I would very much like this result:

```
http://domain.com/something/somestring
```

In other words, I'd like to get rid of /# in my URLs.
I've done this before with .htaccess and mod_rewrite.c and PHP, but I have no clue how to achieve the same result with AngularJS.
Any pointers, tutorial-links, articles, etc. that explains how this can be done, or simply an example would be greatly appreciated.

A few requirements:
I should still be able to do my routing the same way I've done so far:

```js
blogApp.config(['$routeProvider',
  function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
      when('/page/:pagePermaLink', {
        templateUrl: './assets/templates/page.html',
        controller: 'pageCtrl'
      }).
      when('/article', {
       templateUrl: './assets/templates/article.html',
       controller: 'articleCtrl'
      }).
      otherwise({
        redirectTo: '/home',
        templateUrl: './assets/templates/page.html',
        controller: 'mainCtrl'
      });
  }]);
```

The URL query string, like `:pagePermaLink` should still be accessible from the scope:

```js
blogCtrl.controller('pageCtrl', ['$scope', '$routeParams', '$http',
function($scope, $routeParams, $http) {
    var foo = $routeParams.pagePermaLink;
    // ...
}]);
```

Comment: You'll need to configure $locationProvider and this line. 


$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you've already done your rewrites, you should just be able to set `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)`. See https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode

Also, similar stack overflow questions might be of assistance:
[Angular Direct Url without hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31630577/angular-direct-url-without-hash/31631388#31631388)
[$location / switching between html5 and hashbang mode / link rewriting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16677528/location-switching-between-html5-and-hashbang-mode-link-rewriting)

Comment: Thank you! This hit the spot :)