# AngularJS $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) gives error `url is undefined`

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to use html5Mode for urls in AngularJS.

This code runs fine:

```
.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider",
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider.when("/editor", {
            templateUrl: "pages/editor/index.html"
        })
        .when("/docs", {
            templateUrl: "pages/docs/index.html"
        }).otherwise({
            templateUrl: "pages/home/index.html"
        });
    }
]);
```

But this code gives me the error `url is undefined`

```
.config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider",
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider){
        $routeProvider.when("/editor", {
            templateUrl: "pages/editor/index.html"
        })
        .when("/docs", {
            templateUrl: "pages/docs/index.html"
        }).otherwise({
            templateUrl: "pages/home/index.html"
        });

        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

Could the issue be that I have  instead of

What could be the source of this?

Comment: Use `angular.js` instead of minified version that will give you correct information about error

Comment: have you added `<base href="/" />` in the `<head>` tag of your main HTML file  ?

Comment: @Freezsystem I have <base href="/static">

Comment: is the entire site hosted on `http://example.com/static/` then?

Comment: @Claies All resources are. / returns /static/pages/index.html. Once this begins to work, I will rewrite URLs like /docs to / to be compatible with HTML5 mode

Comment: Are you using the same version of angular and angular-route?

Comment: @ChetanSastry Both are 1.3.15

Comment: @ChetanSastry and I just updated them both to 1.4.4 to see if that could be the issue

Comment: @PankajParkar I updated the question with the error from the unminified version of angularjs. It is `url is undefined`.

Comment: @DanielF please confirm you should have both `angular.js` & `angular-route.js` has same version to make them working

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem and I just figured out how to solve this. Well my errors were:

1. I hadn't injected "$locationProvider" I was trying to call the "html5Mode" without referencing the "$locationProvider" at the begining of the function, now I have this:

   ```
   app.config(['$routeProvider','$locationProvider',
   function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {
   $routeProvider
       .when("/", {
           templateUrl: "Views/home/home.html",
           controller: "HomeController"
       })
   .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/'});

   $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);}]);
   ```
2. I had the  wrong, I had: " href="/" "

but I'm running all the app with a local server with Wampp so the base path for my project is "/NAME_OF_THE_PROJECT/" like this:

```
<base href="/SEQUOIA/">
```

With this two corrections I solved all the errors, as I see, you have your base without the last '/', maybe your app is searching "www.localhost.com/staticCONTENT" instead of ".../static/CONTENT".

Ah! I almost forget, I have my .htaccess just the same as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash) and [here](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode)

Comment: Thanks for trying to help. I already fixed those issues without solving my problem, but I will upvote your answer because it is very well thought out.