# Angularjs routing without hash with multiple var

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hash, http-status-code-404, angularjs-routing

Yo everyone.

I searched how to remove the hash(#) from the routing (source: [AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)) but I encountered a problem.

I'll explain.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$routeProvider
.when('/test', {
  controller: TestCtrl,
  templateUrl: 'test.html'
})
.when ('/test/:idPage', {
  controller: PageCtrl,
  templateUrl: 'page.html'
})
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/test' });
```

For the first redirection

 - I've got something like : www.my-website.com/test

all is working fine.

For the second :

 - www.my-website.com/test/hello

and here, **there is a prob**, when I put more than one " / " in the route, no page is loaded and I've got two

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404
>   (Not Found)

in my console.

One called : www.my-website.com/test/page.html and the other : www.my-website.com/test/hello

Hope someone can help me. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Angular 1.4.x requires that 'ngRoute' be included in the module to use `$routeProvider` and `$locationProvider` so include it as a `<script...>`:

- `angular-router` [(see here)](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute).

I am assuming you see something like:

[image]
[image]

To include it in your module:

```
var app = angular.module('someModule', ['ngRoute']);
```

And the controller needs to be in quotes `controller: 'someCtrl'` like:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$routeProvider
.when('/test', {
  controller: 'TestCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'test.html'
})
.when ('/test/:idPage', {
  controller: 'PageCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'page.html'
})
.otherwise({ redirectTo: '/test' });
```

Here is an example that I put together: http://plnkr.co/edit/wyFNoh?p=preview

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['ngRoute']);

app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
          .when('/hello/:idHere', {
            templateUrl: 'resolveView.html',
            controller: 'helloCtrl',
            resolve: {
              exclamVal: function(){
                return '!!!!!!!!!!'
              }
            }
          })
          .when('/default', {
            templateUrl: 'default.html',
            controller: 'defaultCtrl'
          })
          .when('/test', {
            controller: 'testCtrl',
            templateUrl: 'test.html'
          })
          .otherwise({ redirectTo: '/default' });
          $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }]);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $location, $routeParams) {
});
app.controller('testCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  console.log('hi')
});
app.controller('defaultCtrl', function($scope, $routeParams) {
  console.log('Inside defaultCtrl')
});

app.controller('helloCtrl', function($scope, exclamVal, $routeParams) {
  $scope.exclamVal = exclamVal;
  $scope.myVar = $routeParams.idHere;
});
```