# How to remove the # in angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using AngularJS for the first time and am trying to remove the # from the URLs. I am not using NODE or Express. I have the site running in MAMP locally. I am using index.html as the entry point and have 2 templates, header and footer. Then I am keeping all of my individual page content in a partials folder about.html, contact.html etc. I have tried adding

```
<head>

<base href="/">

</head>
```

But it is saying url not found.

I am just using a CDN to import Angular.

Answer (score 4):

This SO post provides some very useful information on this issue: [AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)

It seems that it is needed for any non-HTML5 browsers. You can use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` to try and use the HTML5 method where available though.

Comment: Where would I place this code?

Comment: Put it in a directive in Angular. You could also use `it();` for browser fallbacks. Check here for some examples: https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use real URL instead of hashbangs then first **make the server return the right content for every url**.

i.e. if the homepage consists of nothing but a link and the word "foo" and the link triggers JS which changes the URL to `/bar` and replaces the word "foo" with "bar" **then** if the browser requests `/bar` directly your server needs to send the page with the word "bar" in it (along with all your JS code).

This means you either need to write your code twice (server side and client side) or you need to use Isomorphic JavaScript (and run a server side JavaScript solution).

This is a lot of work, but that is the price of making a robust single page application. You might want to consider not using an SPA (by checking the cost-benefit).

If you aren't going to make the server behave like that, and you still want an SPA, then stick to using hashbang URLs.

---

Once the server is doing the right thing, you just need to tell Angular to use the History API instead of hashbangs.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

Comment: Well I am redesigning a website and need to keep the urls the same. It's a simple website and doesn't need a database or a backend but I don't like having to repeat code so much in each page so I thought this would be a good opportunity to try out Angular for its use of partials and templates. Is there another way to do this? I am new to all this.

Comment: Use a server side CMS / template language.

Comment: A CMS seemed like overkill for this project so I was trying to do it all client side. Would another JS framework do this better. Thanks

Comment: No. Any client side solution is going to have the same problems. If a CMS is going to be overkill, use a more basic template system.

Answer (score 1):

I found an answer to this question, but it appears to be a duplicate of [this issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash).

The hash route is a method of implementing client-side routing on browsers that don't have full HTML5 support.

You can use `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` to tell angular to use HTML5 strategy if available.

All credit for the answer should go to the user, [plus-](https://stackoverflow.com/users/709635/plus) for his answer to the duplicate question.

Comment: @LawrenceAiello Just out of curiosity, is that not what I did with the middle two sentences?  I don't mean that in a negative way, I just want to know if I should be adding more detail or what.  Thanks!