# Is there anyway to change the url parameter of a site?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, seo, url-parameters

All the links of this site contains "#" in it. Also url doesn't look trustworthy. I don't have much knowledge on Javascript and Ajax. But I know this site wasn't made SEO based. This site did by some company and I requested them to change the parameters, and they couldn't.

Is there anyway to change url like this:

http://www.example.com/#/Packages/1/Family
to
http://www.example.com/Family-Packages

I work as a Digital Marketer for this company. And most of the url parameters are unique. If I get any help from you guys, I can transfer it to the site developers.

Comment: That URL structure is a common pattern for Single Page Applications (SPA) and is perfectly trustworthy. I'd be a little concerned that as a DM you were unaware of that and want to change it instead of working to optimise it...

Comment: Agreed. I am sure the site developers will be able to sort this out for you if you ask them

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Thanks for your reply.

Comment: @MuhamedRiyaz: The website is built using AngularJS (https://angularjs.org/), so the `#` you see in the URL is called a hashtag and is safe and standard behaviour, as Rory said. Have a look at this SO question to gain a better understanding of whether or not you should have the hashtag URL structure changed: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash

Comment: @PaparazzoKid Thanks for the link. My only concern is the url structure to be SEO friendly. If this current url structure is good to go, then it's fine.

Answer (score 0):

Ask them to try this

```
history.pushState("", document.title, window.location.pathname + window.location.hash.replace("#", ""));
```