# How to insert # reference in Cordova using angular js

Tags: angularjs, cordova, angularjs-scope, phonegap-build

I have a angular js application which I am trying to wrap it as a Cordova application for mobile.

The url is working fine on browser but redirection on a mobile browser has some issue. When I tried to print the absolute location of the url I am redirected to a url something like

`file:///Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/69F93249-284F-4F04-82CA-14B111CCA50F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B21EB426-7066-4425-82F0-6F73736D880C/ClientManagement.app/www/index.html#/dashboard`

There is a `/` missing from the url when the index page is called.

How can I append the `/` after index.html is loaded

Edit: When the app is first loaded its indicating that following file is loaded:

```
file:///Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/69F93249-284F-4F04-82CA-14B111CCA50F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B21EB426-7066-4425-82F0-6F73736D880C/ClientManagement.app/www/index.html#/
```

But what I intend to load is just

```
file:///Users/mac/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/69F93249-284F-4F04-82CA-14B111CCA50F/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/B21EB426-7066-4425-82F0-6F73736D880C/ClientManagement.app/www/index.html
```

In config.xml I am calling

```
<content src="index.html" />
```

Comment: That is strictly an Angular question. Cordova/Phonegap don't care about the path after the `.html#`

Comment: what's the problem? you want to completely remove the # ? this `index.html#/` doesn't seem wrong to me. what issues do you have?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try,

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

More Information:
[AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)

[Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)