# Polymer Starter Kit - Pretty URLS on Nginx Server

Tags: nginx, polymer, polymer-starter-kit

the Polymer Starter Kit (PSK) contains instructions on using Pretty URLs when hosting on Firebase [HERE](https://github.com/PolymerElements/polymer-starter-kit/blob/master/docs/deploy-to-firebase-pretty-urls.md)

I am attempting to do similar using Nginx Server, but cannot figure out the Location Block for page reloads. Using the sample data that comes with PSK, how would you configure "/users/sam", for example.

Comment: Found answer here:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash

Answer (score 10, accepted):

**nginx config**

```
server {
  listen 80;
  server_name example.com;
  root /home/myuser/psk/dist;
  index index.html;

  location /
  {
    try_files $uri /index.html;
  }
}
```

Make sure to add a **[base url](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/HTML/Element/base)** to your **index.html**. In case of Polymer starter kit & nginx the base element will help direct access to URLs with query parameters such as :  http://example.com/users/Chuck that you can find under "Users" in PSK 1.2.x

```
<html>
  <head>
    <base href="/">
    ...
```

Otherwise nginx will go into a loop without a base URL.

nginx error.log

> rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/index.html"

Browser goes into an infinite cycle loading the index page instead of static files.

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <