# How to make Laravel 5 redirect to Angular routes without the hash (#)?

Tags: angularjs, laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.1, laravel-routing

I am using Laravel 5 with Angular.

By default Angular add `/#/` to the URL.

I don't like that `/#/` so I removed it using `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` from Angular.

Now whenever I try to visit an Angular URL, Laravel refuse to redirect me and instead it causes an error `NotFoundHttpException` saying:

> Sorry, the page you are looking for could not be found.
>
> NotFoundHttpException in RouteCollection.php line 161:

And this is very logical because the route is not defined in the Laravel's route file.

How to solve this?!

**More Details:**

- When I visit `http://whatever.app/#/dashboard/home` everything works fine (laravel knows it's Angular route and then Angular get rid of the # so the URL become `http://whatever.app/dashboard/home` without an error).
- When I visit `http://whatever.app/dashboard/home` Laravel display the error `NotFoundHttpException`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Edit the `render` function in the `app/Exceptions/Handler.php` file:

```
public function render($request, Exception $e)
{
    if ($e instanceof ModelNotFoundException) {
        $e = new NotFoundHttpException($e->getMessage(), $e);
    }

    // handle Angular routes when accessed directly from the browser without the need of the '#'
    if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {

        $url = parse_url($request->url());

        $angular_url = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . '/#' . $url['path'];

        return response()->redirectTo($angular_url);
    }

    return parent::render($request, $e);
}
```

Now whenever you try to visit `http://whatever.app/dashboard/home` laravel detect that the routes does not exist and converts it to `http://whatever.app/#/dashboard/home` which then gets removed by anguar to be `http://whatever.app/dashboard/home` again, but without an error this time :)

Answer (score 1):

The answer of Mahmoud Zalt is correct. But don't consider the query string.

For include the **query** to URL, you will need to change the URL for URI and get the query from that.

```
// handle Angular routes when accessed directly from the browser without the need of the '#'
if ($e instanceof NotFoundHttpException) {

    $url = parse_url($request->getUri());

    $angular_url = $url['scheme'] . '://' . $url['host'] . '/#' . $url['path'] . ( isset($url['query']) ? "?".$url['query'] : "" ) ;;

    return response()->redirectTo($angular_url);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

When you visit below url, Laravel display the error NotFoundHttpException.

```
http://whatever.app/dashboard/home
```

Means laravel don't have this route in routes.php

Probably when your hit http://whatever.app/#/dashboard/home your angular redirect to other url to laravel that works fine(See your angular controller templateUrl and url value for this route, check this and manage from here to your laravel route if your want).

But when you hit url http://whatever.app/dashboard/home , it directly go to laravel route and give error.

So now you want to remove # from url.
These are some solutions link

https://scotch.io/quick-tips/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

[Removing the fragment identifier from AngularJS urls (# symbol)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14771091/removing-the-hashtag-from-angularjs-urls-symbol)

[AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)

Answer (score 0):

use

`missingMethod(){
     return $this->getIndex();
 }`

in controller. This will check existence of your route and if it's not some laravel route - return index.