# routeParams are Empty

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ngroute

I am trying to get URL parameters using $routeParams:

```
var myApp = angular.module('myApp', [
  'ngRoute',
  'appControllers',
  'appFilters',
  'appServices'
]).config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider.when('/admin/organisations/:organisation_id', {
    controller: 'UpdateOrganisationCtrl'
  });
}]);
```

and in my Controller:

```
appControllers.controller('UpdateOrganisationCtrl', ['$rootScope', '$scope', '$http', '$window', '$routeParams',
function($rootScope, $scope, $http, $window, $routeParams) {

    console.log($routeParams.organisation_id);

}]);
```

However I am printing `undefined` as `$routeParams` is `{}` Any thoughts?

Comment: What's the URL that you are using to access this? It would seem there are no parameters in the URL?

Comment: I believe you have to specify params in the route.

Comment: The only thing I can think is maybe the underscore in `organisation_id` is breaking things? Does renaming it as `organisationid` help atall?

Comment: @Rhumborl That was what I thought, but renaming to organisationid did not help at all. Thanks anyways.

Comment: @cale_b For example: http://localhost:3000/admin/organisations/56cde4bf911747ea200d5a63

Comment: @SatejS I couldn't catch that, sorry quite new to this :)

Comment: @HasanCanSaral the way you are accessing URL, that should have enabled `html5mode` on location provider using `$locatioProvider.html5mode(true)`

Comment: @PankajParkar Thanks, I tried that but no luck, `$routeParams` are still `{}` Any thoughts?

Comment: Could you add your view html? Also i can't see templateUrl in route config.

Answer (score 2):

The url you tried to access should be

> [localhost:3000/#/admin/organisations/56cde4bf911747ea200d5a63](http://localhost:3000/#/admin/organisations/56cde4bf911747ea200d5a63)

`ngRoute` will make your application a Single Page Application, where the relevant part of the url for the router will be after `#` (beautifully called the `hashbang`).

[Look at the example:](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngRoute/service/$routeParams)

> // Given:
>   // URL: http://server.com/index.html#/Chapter/1/Section/2?search=moby
>   // Route: /Chapter/:chapterId/Section/:sectionId
>   //
>   // Then
>   $routeParams ==> {chapterId:'1', sectionId:'2', search:'moby'}

However, the url you give could work if you use HTML5Mode for $location service of angular.

See those links for more information:

- [AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)
- [Using $location](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/$location)

Comment: Thanks! I tried to do `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` but `$routeParams` were still `{}` Any thoughts?

Comment: have you verifiy that that url works : localhost:3000/#/admin/organisations/56cde4bf911747ea200d5a63 ?

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot because my application is not a SPA and the URL with a hashbang is redirected to / which is redirected to /dashboard on the server side. So overall I get a redirect to `localhost:3000/dashboard#/admin/organisations/56cde4bf911747ea200d5a63`