# the url can't be found in angularjs

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I am so new in webapi and angularjs.I am trying to develop an angular js .i have this controller:

```
 public class ManageStudentInfoController : Controller
    {
        // GET: ManageStudentInfo
        public ActionResult Index()
        {
            return View();
        }
        public ActionResult AddNewStudent()
        {
            return PartialView("AddStudent");
        }

        public ActionResult ShowStudents()
        {
            return PartialView("ShowAllStudent");
        }

        public ActionResult EditStudent()
        {
            return PartialView("EditStudent");
        }

        public ActionResult DeleteStudent()
        {
            return PartialView("DeleteStudent");
        }
    }
```

And this webapi controller :

```
 public class ManageStudentInfoAPIController : ApiController
    {
        private SchoolManagementEntities db = new SchoolManagementEntities();

        // GET: api/ManageStudentsInfoAPI  
        public IQueryable<Student> GetStudent()
        {
            return db.Students;
        }

        // GET: api/ManageStudentsInfoAPI/5  
        [ResponseType(typeof(Student))]
        public IHttpActionResult GetStudent(int id)
        {
            Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            return Ok(student);
        }

        // PUT: api/ManageStudentsInfoAPI/5  
        [ResponseType(typeof(void))]
        public IHttpActionResult PutStudent(int id, Student student)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            if (id != student.StudentID)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            db.Entry(student).State = EntityState.Modified;

            try
            {
                db.SaveChanges();
            }
            catch (DbUpdateConcurrencyException)
            {
                if (!StudentExists(id))
                {
                    return NotFound();
                }
                else
                {
                    throw;
                }
            }

            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent);
        }

        // POST: api/ManageStudentsInfoAPI  
        [ResponseType(typeof(Student))]
        public IHttpActionResult PostStudent(Student student)
        {
            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            db.Students.Add(student);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return CreatedAtRoute("DefaultApi", new { id = student.StudentID }, student);
        }

        // DELETE: api/ManageStudentsInfoAPI/5  
        [ResponseType(typeof(Student))]
        public IHttpActionResult DeleteStudent(int id)
        {
            Student student = db.Students.Find(id);
            if (student == null)
            {
                return NotFound();
            }

            db.Students.Remove(student);
            db.SaveChanges();

            return Ok(student);
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }

        private bool StudentExists(int id)
        {
            return db.Students.Count(e => e.StudentID == id) > 0;
        }
    }
```

I have this js files in myscript folder :

[image]

The module file :

```
var app = angular.module("ApplicationModule", ["ngRoute"]);

app.factory("ShareData", function () {
    return { value: 0 }
});

//Showing Routing  
app.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    debugger;
    $routeProvider.when('/showstudents',
                        {
                            templateUrl: 'ManageStudentInfo/ShowStudents',
                            controller: 'ShowStudentsController'
                        });
    $routeProvider.when('/addstudent',
                        {
                            templateUrl: 'ManageStudentInfo/AddNewStudent',
                            controller: 'AddStudentController'
                        });
    $routeProvider.when("/editStudent",
                        {
                            templateUrl: 'ManageStudentInfo/EditStudent',
                            controller: 'EditStudentController'
                        });
    $routeProvider.when('/deleteStudent',
                        {
                            templateUrl: 'ManageStudentInfo/DeleteStudent',
                            controller: 'DeleteStudentController'
                        });
    $routeProvider.otherwise(
                        {
                            redirectTo: '/'
                        });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true).hashPrefix('!')
}]);
```

The service.js file :

```
app.service("SPACRUDService", function ($http) {

    //Read all Students  
    this.getStudents = function () {

        return $http.get("/api/ManageStudentInfoAPI");
    };

    //Fundction to Read Student by Student ID  
    this.getStudent = function (id) {
        return $http.get("/api/ManageStudentInfoAPI/" + id);
    };

    //Function to create new Student  
    this.post = function (Student) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "post",
            url: "/api/ManageStudentInfoAPI",
            data: Student
        });
        return request;
    };

    //Edit Student By ID   
    this.put = function (id, Student) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "put",
            url: "/api/ManageStudentInfoAPI/" + id,
            data: Student
        });
        return request;
    };

    //Delete Student By Student ID  
    this.delete = function (id) {
        var request = $http({
            method: "delete",
            url: "/api/ManageStudentInfoAPI/" + id
        });
        return request;
    };
});
```

And my index.html view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "SPA";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<link href="~/Content/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<body data-ng-app="ApplicationModule">
    <div>
        <div>
            <div>
                <table cellpadding="5" cellspacing="6" width="100%" style="background-color:whitesmoke; border:solid 4px green;">
                    <tr>
                        <td style="border: solid 1px gray; width:170px; text-align:center;"><a href="managestudentinfo/showstudents"> Show All Students </a></td>
                        <td style="border: solid 1px gray; width:170px; text-align:center;"><a href="managestudentinfo/AddNewStudent"> Add New Student </a></td>
                        <td></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </div>
            <div>
                <div data-ng-view></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</body>

@section scripts{
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/angular-route.min.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/MyScripts/Module.js")"></script>
    <script src="~/MyScripts/Services.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/MyScripts/ShowStudentsController.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/MyScripts/AddStudentController.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/MyScripts/EditStudentController.js")"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="@Url.Content("~/MyScripts/DeleteStudentController.js")"></script>
}
```

other files are available if you need .the problem is when i run the project and when i go to this url :`http://localhost:5411/showstudents`  the browser can't find the url  .

```
The resource cannot be found.

Description: HTTP 404. The resource you are looking for (or one of its dependencies) could have been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.  Please review the following URL and make sure that it is spelled correctly. 

Requested URL: /showstudents
```

Comment: Are you running you webapi on iisexpress @ port 5411 ?

Comment: @dreamweiver yes it works

Comment: are you saying your issue is resolved ?

Comment: No i don't say ,i said that my webapi works fine just that,not all my project,because i test my webapi controller and it works

Comment: hmm, then what exactly is the issue ? obviously this would not work, since this is not your webapi ,`http://localhost:5411/showstudents` url.  could you explain more what exactly is your issue

Comment: When i call http://localhost:5411/showstudents the angular should call the action ShowStudents,but it doesn't call that,but the webapi works fine because when i call http://localhost:5411/showstudents/api/ManageStudentInfoAPI/get it returns the rows

Comment: Install this: https://github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle
It will reveal all your routes. Plus, it provides a nice and clean documentation. You can even call your api from there, and see the assembled url. 
As simple as Install-Package Swashbuckle and then go to localhost:PORT_HERE/swagger

Answer (score 0):

Don't forget the "api" in your url:

http://localhost:5411/api/showstudents

Comment: I don't think so ,because i handle that in my module and service,am i right ?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access to a non-existent URI: `localhost:5411/showstudents` does not exist on your server.

Your `/showstudents` route mapping works ONLY inside AngularJS, the correct URI using your actual configuration is: `localhost:5411/#/showstudents` (notice the hash). That's because the routing is handled by AngularJS in JavaScript, not by the server.

You can remove the dependency from the hash in the URI following instructions in this question: [AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash) , but please note that this will work only if you follow a link inside your already generated AngularJS View.

Before continue I suggest you to read more about [how routing works inside AngularJS](https://docs.angularjs.org/tutorial/step_07).

Answer (score 0):

First, you can't use a route `'ManageStudentInfo/ShowStudents'` as `templateurl`. It should be a HTML file that will load when you access the state and you have a ActionResult method in your name as

```
 public ActionResult ShowStudents()
        {
            return PartialView("ShowAllStudent");
        }
```

and an angular route state as

```
$routeProvider.when('/showstudents',
    {
       templateUrl: 'ManageStudentInfo/ShowStudents',
       controller: 'ShowStudentsController'
    });
```

Both names are the same, so when you are requesting this [url](http://localhost:5411/showstudents), angular is trying to load its state and asp.net is trying to load its Actionresult. Both are conflicting, so give them different names, also you can try url like this with controller name

```
http://localhost:5411/ManageStudentInfo/showstudents
```

May it will help

Answer (score 0):

While not a *direct answer* to your question, here is a tool/technique **that will permit you to resolve that kind of issue**.

**Swashbuckle** is a tool that permit you to have access to the Swagger Spec of your WebApi.

That means, you will be able to see how your **WebApi** should be call with **HTTP**.

### How to install Swashbuckle

Available as a nuget: `Install-Package Swashbuckle`
Doc and source here: github.com/domaindrivendev/Swashbuckle

### What it permits

It will reveal all your routes. Plus, it provides a nice and clean documentation. 
You can even call your api from there, and see the assembled url.

As simple as  and then go to localhost:PORT_HERE/swagger

### Want to try it first

See: http://petstore.swagger.io/#!/pet/getPetById

Answer (score 0):

URL: http://localhost:5411/showstudents is defined in angular and not in mvc thus 404

SOLUTION:

update your RegisterRoute in routeconfig.cs file as

```
public static void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.IgnoreRoute("{resource}.axd/{*pathInfo}");

        routes.MapRoute(
            name: "Default",
            url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional },
            constraints: new { controller = "Home|Api|Account|App|token" } // this is basically a regular expression
        );
        routes.MapRoute(
            "Angular",
            "{*url}",
            defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index" }
        );
    }
```

this will redirect all 404 routing from mvc to angular routes

check for more details :
http://www.mithunvp.com/using-angular-2-asp-net-mvc-5-visual-studio/