# links outside of ng-view redirect to the pages inside ng-view

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am not sure how to name the question, but here is my situation

My template is like this:

├── index.html
├── ...
├── account
│   ├── index.html
│   ├── authorization
│   │   ├── login.html
│   │   ├── signup.html
│   │   └── dashboard

So the first index page is the front page, the second index page contains ng-view which is the template for the login page, signup page, and dashboard page.

I have made:

```
app.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
    $routeProvider.
        when('/login', {
            title: 'Login',
            templateUrl: 'authorization/login.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .when('/signup', {
            title: 'Signup',
            templateUrl: 'authorization/signup.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .when('/dashboard', {
            title: 'dashboard',
            templateUrl: 'authorization/dashboard/index.html',
            controller: 'authCtrl'
        })
        .otherwise({
            redirectTo: "/login"
        });
    }
])
.run(['$rootScope', '$location', 'apiService', function ($rootScope, $location, apiService) {...
}]);
```

However, I want to add two links on the first index page, one redirect to the login page and the other one to the register page. Because both of login.html and signup.html are inside ng-view, I could not use `<a href="account"></a>`, since it will only go to the login page.

I have tried:

```
<div class="nav_item_extra"><a class="loggedIn" href="account/authorization/login">Sign in</a></div>
<div class="nav_item_extra"><a class="loggedIn" href="account/authorization/signup.html">Register</a></div>
```

Neither of them works.

Could someone helps me how to make the links? Thank you

Comment: You should use ui-sref attribute with state name instead of href. ex: your second link just tries to hit the template path instead of actual state

Comment: @NimaMarashi Is there anyway without using ui-router? I did not use on this site yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only miss '#' (hash tag on your href)

```
<div class="nav_item_extra"><a class="loggedIn" href="#/login">Sign in</a>
</div>
<div class="nav_item_extra"><a class="loggedIn" href="#/signup">Register</a>
</div>
```

Comment: oh thank you... I do not know why I did not try it... I thought "#" is something disallowed to make link path....

Comment: im glad it helped :) someone explain about the '#' tag in here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash?answertab=active#tab-top

Answer (score 0):

This sould work:

```
<div class="nav_item_extra"><a class="loggedIn" href="login">Sign in</a></div>
<div class="nav_item_extra"><a class="loggedIn" href="signup">Register</a></div>
```

Comment: it does not, it shows 404 because it could not find the /login. And login.html and signup.html are actually stored in public_html/partner/account/authorization. By using "/login", it will goes to my root folder.

Comment: Is there any reason for having '/' before each route? why not 'login' instead of '/login' ? update my answer