# path setting in angular with remove % form the path and display

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

Yesterday of good man help me  a lot for passing the parameter form one page to another in ionic / angular  but now the problem aries is that when i passes the parameter  in it contain % symbol  .

Eg.  its looks like this http://localhost:8100/#/Deals/Paytm.com%20CPS%20-%20India 
 where i want to show like this http://localhost:8100/#/Deals/Paytm.com CPS - India .

By which i want to display display data . How can i archive this and display the data .

Following is our code ..

```
 <div class="item col-sm-2 col-sm-3 col-md-2 " ng-repeat="da in myData | unique: 'store_image'" >
            <div class="thumbnail " >

                   <img class="thumbnail  img-responsive " ng-src="{{ da.store_image}}" 
ng-click="showData(da.offer_name, $index)"
                    />   
                <div class="caption">
                    <b class="group inner list-group-item-heading center-block">
                        {{da.offer_name | limitTo: 12 }} Deals </b>

                <a class="item item-text-wrap" ng-href="#/Deals/{{da.offer_name }}">View Deal</a>

                  </div>
                </div>
            </div>

            </div>
```

Angular js

```
.controller('menuCtrl', function($scope,$http) {


     $http.get("http://tools.vcommission.com/api/coupons.php?apikey=e159f64e3dd49fddc3bb21dcda70f10c6670ea91aac30c7cb1d4ed37b20c45b8").then(function (response) {
      $scope.myData = response.data;
      $scope.offerName = ''; //set initially
      $scope.selectedIndex = -1;
      $scope.filteredOffers = [];



  });
 $scope.showData = function(offer_name, index) {
        $scope.offerName = offer_name;
      $scope.filteredOffers = $scope.myData.filter(function(offer) {
        return offer.offer_name == $scope.offerName;
      });
        $scope.selectedIndex = index;

      }


})
```

Deals page

```
 <div ng-repeat="offer in filteredOffers">
  <div class="couponCode">{{offer.coupon_code}}</div>
  <div class="couponTitle">{{offer.coupon_title}}</div>
  <div class="couponDescription">{{offer.coupon_Description}}</div>
</div>

 </ion-content>
```

and Finally

Routes

```
.state('Deals', {
      url: '/Deals/:offer_name',
      templateUrl: 'temp/deal.html',
      controller: 'menuCtrl'
    })
```

how to fetch data from url parameter

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)

Comment: you can't have **spaces** in a URL, `%20` is the code for a space character.  if your property is going to be used as a URL parameter, it should be restricted to not having spaces/special characters.

Comment: OK BUT HOW TO FATCH RESULTS .. FORM THIS