# Handle the MEAN-stack application address without fragment '#'

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, url-rewriting, angular-ui-router

**Edit 1:** Here is [a mini code](https://github.com/chengtie/mini-mean) I made that reproduces the error. Please follow `README.md` to install.

**Edit 2:** Finally, I found one solution. Besides `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` (`$locationProvider.hashPrefix('')` is NOT necessary for me) and `<base href="/" />`, I need to add the follows in `routes/index.js`, rather than `app.js`. Then, we do NOT need to add anything more to `app.js` or nginx or apache like [this thread](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode) mentions.

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var path = require('path');
... ...
router.get('*', function(req, res) {
    res.sendfile('./views/index.html'); // load our public/index.html sendFile
    // res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'views') }); // does not work
});
```

One problem is, **in the server console, it gives `express deprecated res.sendfile: Use res.sendFile instead routes/index.js:461:9`. But `res.sendFile('index.html', { root: path.join(__dirname, 'views') });` can not help, it returns 404 error.**

My express version is `~4.14.0`... does anyone know how to fix that?

**OP:**

I develop in Mac with Apache a MEAN-stack application that can be requested by 
`https://localhost:3000/#/home`. In production with an NGINX server, the application can be requested by
 `https://www.myapp.io/#/home`. The fragment-identifier `#` is needed in all cases because of `angular ui-router`.

So I wanted to make pretty url without `#` (eg, `https://www.myapp.io/home`, `https://localhost:3000/home`) work. I have done the following:

1. added `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true); $locationProvider.hashPrefix('')` in `app.config(['$stateProvider'...`.
2. added `<base href="/" />` in `index.html`

As a result, `https://localhost:3000/#/home` changes automatically to `https://localhost:3000/home` in the browser bar, similarly for `https://www.myapp.io/#/home`.

However, directly entering `https://localhost:3000/home` or `https://www.myapp.io/home` in the browser will raise an error (I don't know how to turn previous `<h1><%= message %></h1><h2><%= error.status %></h2><pre><%= error.stack %></pre>` in `error.ejs` to `error.html`, so I don't have more details).

**So now, the goal is to make `https://localhost:3000/home` and `https://www.myapp.io/home` work.**

By following [this thread](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions#how-to-configure-your-server-to-work-with-html5mode), I added the follows to `app.js`:

```
app.use('/js', express.static(__dirname + '/js'));
app.use('/dist', express.static(__dirname + '/../dist'));
app.use('/css', express.static(__dirname + '/css'));
app.use('/partials', express.static(__dirname + '/partials'));    
app.all('/*', function(req, res, next) {
    res.sendFile('index.html', { root: __dirname });
});
```

And in Apache of Mac, here is my `httpd-vhosts.conf`, after restarting `apache`, 
`https://localhost:3000/home` still returns an error.

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerName localhost
    DocumentRoot "/Users/SoftTimur"

    SSLEngine on
    SSLCipherSuite ALL:!ADH:!EXPORT56:RC4+RSA:+HIGH:+MEDIUM:+LOW:+SSLv2:+EXP:+eNULL
    SSLCertificateFile /etc/apache2/ssl/localhost.crt
    SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/apache2/ssl/localhost.key

    <Directory "/Users/SoftTimur">
        RewriteEngine on

        # Don't rewrite files or directories
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
        RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
        RewriteRule ^ - [L]

        # Rewrite everything else to index.html to allow html5 state links
        RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]

        Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
        AllowOverride All
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
        Require all granted
    </Directory>
</VirtualHost>
```

In production, here is the NGINX server block. After restarting NGINX, `https://www.myapp.io/home` still returns an error.

```
server {
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name myapp.io www.myapp.io;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.io/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/myapp.io/privkey.pem;

    ssl_protocols TLSv1 TLSv1.1 TLSv1.2;
    ssl_prefer_server_ciphers on;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/ssl/certs/dhparam.pem;
    ssl_ciphers 'ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-ECDSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256:ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384:EC$
    ssl_session_timeout 1d;
    ssl_stapling on;
    ssl_stapling_verify on;
    add_header Strict-Transport-Security max-age=15768000;

    index index.html;

    root /opt/myapp;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
    }

    location ~ /.well-known {
        allow all;
    }

    location / {
        proxy_set_header    Host                $host;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-For     $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header    X-Forwarded-Proto   $scheme;
        proxy_set_header    Accept-Encoding     "";
        proxy_set_header    Proxy               "";
        proxy_pass          https://127.0.0.1:3000;

        # These three lines added as per https://github.com/socketio/socket.io/issues/1942 to remove sock$

        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header   Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header   Connection "upgrade";
    }
}
```

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

This might useful stuff,

[AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)

Also, use this line in your express server file.
`app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'client folder')));`

this will directly finds your index.html file in that views folder and loads it

Answer (score 0):

try this in your express server

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.get('*', function (req, res) { res.sendFile(__dirname + '/views/index.html'); });
```

and in your angular app:

```
$locationProvider.hashPrefix('!').html5Mode({
    enabled: true
});
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

and you still need the `<base href="/">` in your index.html

let me know if this works for you

EDIT:

I just found your app in https://github.com/chengtie/mini-mean,
looks like your app.use order is wrong. Please copy paste this in your express server and check if it's okay now. [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/XH0Zu5G1)

Comment: It does load the page, but with some other strange errors. Eg, it tried to load `https://localhost:3000/register` (`POST /register`) which should not be executed. Could you tell me precisely why app.use order was wrong in the initial file? Then I will just re-order it on my side...

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't need Apache or Nginx to run NodeJs in development, just `node server.js` is enough
2. Express gave you that error because you are using a deprecated API `res.sendfile` please use res.sendFile (capital F)
3. Some info for doing SPA:

   - When you have the '#' in your URL, the browser interpret it as a local reference and thus, won't send new request to the server
   - By enabling `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` you are now using html5 push state to navigate around your application history and (if I'm not mistaken you are happening to be using) angular effectively remove the '#' in url
   - Without the '#' (hash-bang) browser will interpret it as a new request and send it to server, so you have to map all requests from server to your SPA entry file
   - For exact steps of replicating this behavior, consult this article: https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag (the base href in your entry file is important)

Answer (score -1):

If it's just about the #. You can remove it in Angular itself.

Just inject locationProvider at your app entry and set htmlMode to true. In your index.html set the baseUrl.

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)
```

And in you index.html add:

```
<base href="/" />
```

That will generate your urls without the #. Does that help?

Comment: No, it does not help. I have already done this, and it works, but my question is about dealing the url without `#`.

Comment: Sorry, just read it thoroughly. Your question has a lot of "distractions". But I should have read better. So your question is actually: Why won't it work once deployed? Because I can't really pinpoint your exact question...

Comment: My question is: given `https://localhost:3000/#/home` and `https://www.myapp.io/#/home` work, how to make `https://localhost:3000/home` and `https://www.myapp.io/home` work?

Comment: This is the part I don't get (sorry, really trying, because I prob can fix it if I know the exact issue). So locally it works with the #? And "production" you want it without? And there is no error in your console output?

Comment: `localhost` means development in my mac; `www.myapp.io` means the production. Regarding `#`, they have the same behaviour: they work with `#`, but do not work without `#`. I want to make them work even without `#`.

Comment: Then first I would make it work without the hash on your localhost. Then make it work in your server. I'm sure you won't be needing serverside "hacks" or http rewrites to get it to work. So on your localhost: Does it work? And what browser are you testing it in? And do you use debugging tools like e.a. Batarang or Ng-inspector? Because you need to completely turn them of, because sometimes they interfere with loading behaviour.

Comment: I don't think the problem is about "testing", given what the 3 blocks of code do is not clear yet...

Comment: Well, sorry can't help you then. I just don't have enough info and you're not really answering questions, so going to be difficult. But good luck with solving it man.