# Remove '#' in Angularjs - Ui.router urls

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, codeigniter, angular-routing, pretty-urls

In my project, there are two root folders

1.'tpapp' for angular js codes(client side) and

2.'tp_app' for codeignitor(server side).Apache as server.
I am using ui.router ver.0.2.8.I want to remove '#' symbols from the urls.

In my app.js file

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

In my index.html file

```
<base href="/tpapp">
```

In my .htaccess file

```
 <IfModule authz_core_module>
        Require all denied
    </IfModule>
    <IfModule !authz_core_module>
        Deny from all
 </IfModule>
```

RewriteEngine On

```
# If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTP} off
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}/index.html
</IfModule>
```

So I got clean url as 'http://localhost/tpapp/login' but when refresh or put url directly in browser shows "404 Error".

How to remove this issue?

Thanks in advance.I tried the solution for the same question asked before.But none worked for me.

Comment: changes  `<base href="/tpapp">` to  `<base href="/">`

Comment: @RameshRajendran I tried that then js files and css are not loading.eg:<script src="angular/controller/login_controller.js"></script>

Comment: You could add the `/tpapp` before wherever call the `css\images\etc..`

Comment: @RameshRajendran I tried this , but when refresh the page , it shows 404 error

Comment: That answer you can get from the 4th answer which is @Yagiz Ozturk  answered https://stackoverflow.com/a/27011093/2218635

Comment: @RameshRajendran Thats for IIS server

Comment: Then let's see this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909743/2218635

Comment: @RameshRajendran  This is not working for me.