# Use hash without #! in angularjs without router

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I need to create my own router like code in angularjs because I need to add routes dynamically using simple plugins system. I have navigation like this:

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#page1">page1</a></li>
    <li><a href="#page2">page2</a></li>
</ul>
```

and my controller look like this:

```
app.controller('main', function($scope) {
    let set = () => {
        this.panel = location.hash.replace(/^#/, '');
    };

    $(window).on('hashchange', () => {
        $scope.$apply(set);
    });
    set();
});
```

I will show different panel depend on controller panel property.

but when I click on the link I've got `#!#page1` how can I prevent `#!#`  and have #page1 as hash? Or maybe just #!/page1 (but without adding router) because when I'm adding href="page1" I've got normal link to page that don't exists (outside of angular).

Comment: write `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);` in `.config()` block

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)

Comment: @WilliamHampshire that different question because I don't use router.

Comment: ...maybe you should?  Why roll your own here?

Comment: @DanielBeck as I've said in the question I need to add plugins, dynamic routes, so I do that by injecting components in html using twig. I can't use ui-router or ng-router because all routes need to be defined in config and I don't want to create js file as twig template because I'm using webpack.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats the hash bang you need to remove (#!). For that you need to add base tag in the index.html of yours

```
<base href="/">
```

and set @locationProvider html mode to true, for example:

```
angular.module('myApp').config(function ($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true); //activate HTML5 Mode
});
```

the last # i.e. (#page1) would be there as you are setting the id to traverse to that section

Comment: Now the problem is that href="/logout" don't redirect but use history API to change url.

Comment: In order to make normal ulrls work you need to add `ng-click="$event.stopPropagation()"`