# Error routing views in angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Hello today I'm learning how to configure routes, views and controllers with Angularjs.
After a lots of trials and errors i ended up in a (mostly) clear URL, but while I expect something link `localhost/home.html/model` I just got `localhost/model`. What's wrong?

Here is my code

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>HOME PAGE</title>
    <script src="angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="angular-route.min.js"></script>
    <script>
        var demoApp = angular.module('demoApp', ['ngRoute']);
        demoApp.config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when('/model', {
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: '/view1.html'
                })
                .when('/house', {
                    controller: 'SimpleController',
                    templateUrl: '/view2.html'
                })
                .otherwhise({ redirectTo: '/home' });
        });
        demoApp.controller('SimpleController', function ($scope) {
            $scope.cpu = [
                { house: 'Intel', model: 'I7' },
                { house: 'Intel', model: 'I3' },
                { house: 'Intel', model: 'Pentium' },
                { house: 'AMD', model: 'Ryzen' },
                { house: 'AMD', model: 'Athlon' },
                { house: 'AMD', model: 'Sempron' },
                { house: 'Qualcomm', model: 'Snapdragon' },
                { house: 'Mediatek', model: 'Helio' },
            ];
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    </script>
    <base href="/">
</head>
<body ng-app="demoApp">
    <div ng-controller="SimpleController">
        <a href="/model">Modello</a>
        <a href="/house">Casa produttrice</a>
        <div ng-view="">
            PROVA
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: `<a href="model">Modello</a> <a href="house">Casa produttrice</a>` remove the `/`

Comment: Just tried, the link is still wrong...

Comment: Since you enabled `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);`, how do you handle routing? Have you modified your `.htaccess`?

Comment: Err... no... I just followed [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)

Comment: You can't just remove the hash-bang `#!/` (or `#/`) in your URL; from your link you can see the second answer changes the routing in `.htaccess`. The issue arrises when you try to refresh on some page, it will show 404 page since routing is not using a hash-bang anymore

Comment: Ok, thanks, but your comments now gives me two new way of moving:  
1) he says to "adjust `.htaccess` for my need" now, since I'm new to all this stuff could you please provide me a guide or a tutorial for those things?  
2) if I just remove `$locationProvider.html5mode` how could I fix the code to actually show the same list, in the current page, in two different way?

Comment: (2) is easier, just replace links such as `href="/model"` with `href="#!/model"`. Your `$routeProvider` will pick anything after a hash-bang, so your `.when('/model', {` is already correct and doesn't require any changes. After that your URL would look like this `localhost/#!/model`

Comment: I changed the `href` according to your suggestion and now my URL is (as expected) `http://localhost:64832/home.html#!/model` . My problem is that I still got a blank page with just two links whose purpose is just to change the url. It's like there is no actual binding of `view1.html` in `home.html`'s `<div>`...

Comment: I don't get why you have `home.html` as part of your hash-bang. (what is your folder structure?)

Comment: I got a single folder in which I put home.html, view1 and view2.html, the two scripts needed by my page and some other stuff for other learning pages i already made https://imgur.com/DbERrNp  EDIT: i tried to manually write `http://localhost:64832/#!/model` and i got a server error saying that the server isn't configured to allow the directory content viewing

Comment: for home page, try adding `.when('/', {templateUrl: '/home.html'})` to your config. As for server issues, make sure it points to your folder correctly

Comment: There is no (explicit) server, since I'm only trying to open local html files lol

Comment: JavaScript alone needs a runtime environment / server, I don't know what you expected. Try Node.js with `http-server` or some Apache server like XAMPP or MAMP (mac).

Comment: ok, I think this is the symptom of the fact I should stop learning by myself and talk to someone phisically, to learn with a guide. Thank you for your answers and sorry for wasting your time