# Angular UI router matching wrong route

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

My app have 3 routes (html5 mode):

```
/app/home
/app/foo
/something-random
```

and then a fallback to /app/home if nothing match. Those are defined like this:

```
$stateProvider
            .state('app', {
                url: '/app',
                abstract: true,
                templateUrl: 'frame.html',
                controller: 'frame'
            })
            .state('app.home', {
                url: '/home',
                params: {
                    scrollTo: null
                },
                views: {
                    sectionHolder: {
                        templateUrl: 'home.html',
                        controller: 'home'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('app.foo', {
                url: '/foo',
                params: {
                    scrollTo: null
                },
                views: {
                    sectionHolder: {
                        templateUrl: 'foo.html'
                        controller: 'foo'
                    }
                }
            })
            .state('extra', {
                url: '/:slug',
                templateUrl: 'extra.html',
                controller: 'extra'
            });

$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/app/home');
```

This is the result:

```
mysite.com/app/home            ->   works
mysite.com/app/foo             ->   works
mysite.com/something-random    ->   works
mysite.com                     ->   matches the extra route and does not fallsback to /app/home as intended.
```

According to [documentation](https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-router/wiki/URL-Routing):

> '/user/:id' - Matches '/user/bob' or '/user/1234!!!' or even '/user/'
>   but not '/user' or '/user/bob/details'. The second path segment will
>   be captured as the parameter 'id'.

But in my cases is matching an empty slug.

Comment: I'm pretty sure it falls back to the hash-bang, so you should have `mysite.com/#!/`. If you removed the hash, then check how you resolved your routing in `.htaccess`

Comment: @AlekseySolovey im using html5 mode

Comment: that's not enough, you also need to configure your routing (otherwise on refresh, it will show 404), [more about it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909743/8495123)

Comment: @AlekseySolovey this has nothing to do with backend configuration

Comment: Do you need something like `$urlRouterProvider.when('', '/home');` to forward requests from the root to your /home?