# Removing # from Url Angular JS

Tags: angularjs, url, url-routing

I have a url something like this:
http://localhost:5000/superadmin#/login

ANd i want to have it in 
http://localhost:5000/superadmin/#/login

So, that i can remove the # by using html5Mode() method

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

The # is an old browser shortcircuit which doesn't fire the request, which allows many js frameworks to build their own clientside rerouting on top of that.

You can remove with location service check the code below:

https://scotch.io/tutorials/pretty-urls-in-angularjs-removing-the-hashtag

Comment: http://localhost:5000/superadmin#/login     I am not getting it in the default format. Problem is i am getting it in http://my.website.com/about#/about

Comment: You can use $locationProvider.html5Mode(true) to tell angular to use HTML5 strategy if available.

Answer (score 0):

Try this below settings

> add **html5Mode(true)** in router config;

```
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {       
    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

> In html head add **base** tag

```
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">    
    <base href="/">
</head>
```

for more details, Please checkout this discussion : [AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)

Comment: I have been trying this! but unsuccessful. it does works for routes like "/#" and "/superadmin/#" but not for  "/superadmin#"