# After AngularJS hash removal URL refresh is not working

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hash

Well, that's pretty much it. I removed the hashes from the url of my AngularJS app via $locationProvider. Nevertheless, now when I refresh or directly copy-paste the url onto the browser search bar everything explodes. It actually gives me a 404.

Do you have any ideas on why is this happening?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/a/17909743/575527

Comment: Have you set the base tag in base html?

Comment: Yes, I did. No solution yet :S