# How can I tailor Angular js urls to be user friendly?

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

We are continuing the development of our website that uses AngularJS on the frontend, and Yii 1.1 on the backend.

Our application allows users to create their own community groups
When a user clicks on a group called "ABC Group" (who's ID is 9), the url is

http://ourwebsite.com/#/app/group/9/content/list

We want to change this however to look like:

http://ourwebsite.com/abcgroup/

we are using ui-router

Any ideas how to do this?
Also, why does angular use the "#" at all?

Answer (score 1):

You have to inject  **$locationProvider** and set the property **html5Mode** true as follow:-

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

Eg:-

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.config(['$routeProvider', '$locationProvider', function($routeProvider, 
$locationProvider) {

$routeProvider.
  when('/contact', {templateUrl: 'xyz/contact.html',   controller: mycontroller})
  .otherwise({redirectTo: '/home.html'});

$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

}]);

Even you can check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)

if you are using **ui-router** you can do the same with **$stateProvider**

```
angular.module('myModule', [])
.config(['$stateProvider', '$locationProvider', function($stateProvider, 
$locationProvider) {
$stateProvider
    .state("contact",
        {
            url: "xyz/contact",
            views: {
                'content': {
                    templateUrl: "Views/xyz/contact.html",
                    controller: "contactController"
                }
            }
        })
 $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
]);
```