# How to remove # in url in angular 5?

Tags: angular, typescript, url

Actually i am using angular 5 for my project, I need to remove # from my url.
here is my url
`http://localhost:4200/#/product/add`.
After published in my domain it works properly but while refresh the page it shows 404 error because of **#** in my url. Is it possible to do this?

- `Need to remove # in url`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)

Comment: I need in angular 5. is it possible?

Comment: Is reload working for you ? On reload it should give error 404

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You need to change your [LocationStrategy](https://angular.io/guide/router#appendix-locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles) to [PathLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/PathLocationStrategy)

By default angular use the PathLocationStrategy, that said looks like you're probably defining [HashLocationStrategy](https://angular.io/api/common/HashLocationStrategy) yourself. Look for some sort of this code in your project:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })
```

In this case just remove the useHash like so:

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes)
```

Or maybe

```
[Location, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
```

In this case change HashLocationStrategy to PathLocationStrategy like so:

```
[Location, {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}]
```

Comment: @perumalN Glad to help

Comment: Simple but efficient

Comment: For prod build this solution not working for me. I using angular 8 and publishing on S3. Can you help me out in this .

Comment: @ParvindraSingh Maybe you need to set `base-href ./` on build, something like this: `ng build --prod --base-href ./`

Comment: I tried this solution as well, But seems like i need to change my build from s3 to another server, might be on EC2 and then change settings in htdocs.  But thanks for the solution you reverted.

Comment: @benshabatnoam Thanks mate !

Comment: Working Fine. But if we refresh that page pressing F5, page returns 404 error. how to overcome it?

Comment: @RajaSekaran you'll need to configure your server to redirect to index.html on 404. I can't instruct you how to do it as it depends on which server you're hosting your site at.