# Added # to the end of the browser address in Angular 9

Tags: angular

I had a problem after uploading the project and by refreshing the page, I returned to the main page and used HashLocationStrategy to fix the problem as follows.

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    .
    .
    .
],
  imports: [
   .
   .
   .
  ],
  providers: [
    { provide: DateAdapter, useClass: MaterialPersianDateAdapter, deps: [MAT_DATE_LOCALE] },
    { provide: MAT_DATE_FORMATS, useValue: PERSIAN_DATE_FORMATS },
    { provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy }
  ],
})
```

**The problem I have is that the browser address of a # is added to the end, how can I prevent # from being added?**

```
http://localhost:4200/#/   ===> http://localhost:4200
http://localhost:4200/#/Admin  ===> http://localhost:4200/Admin
```

Comment: That's how the hash location strategy works, what were you expecting?

Comment: check this out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651445/how-to-remove-in-url-in-angular-5

Answer (score 3):

if you need LocationStrategy, try changing HashLocationStrategy to PathLocationStrategy:

```
 {provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: PathLocationStrategy}
```

Comment: By doing this, we will encounter a 404 error when refreshing the page