# How do i remove # from the url for my one page website links

Tags: javascript, html

I have a website (i.e: https://example.com) with five navigation links (**About**, **Services**, **Case Studies**, **Blog** & **Contact**) and same in the footer out of which these three (**About**, **Services** & **Case Studies**)are one page links (i.e when we click on these links it takes us to a section on the same page (index.html)) but when i click on those links it shows /# (hashtag) in the URL. For example, if i am on index.html and click on about it takes me to the about section on the page but it shows this in the url: https://example.com/#about and i want it to display https://example.com/about or just https://example.com but still do the functionality which is taking me to the section.

Here is the code for nav html:

```
<nav>
                <ul class="navbar">
                    <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#services">Services</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#case_studies">Case Studies</a></li>
                    <li><a href="/blog.html">Blog</a></li>
                    <li><a class="btn" href="/contact.html">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Here are the sample pictures:

**Navbar**
[image: navbar picture]

**URL**
[image: url picture]

**I am not good with JS frameworks and other languages except HTML & CSS so if the solutions unclodes steps outside of this please try to explain it in details, Thank you.**

I have tried this solution: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/269044/remove-fragment-in-url-with-javascript-w-out-causing-page-reload](https://stackoverflow.com) but no luck.

Comment: The FIRST result on google for "angular remove # from url" is: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651445/how-to-remove-in-url-in-angular-5

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to remove # in url in angular 5?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53651445/how-to-remove-in-url-in-angular-5)

Comment: Are you using Angular or not?

Comment: I am not using anugular

Comment: But you have `angular` tagged?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`history.replaceState`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/History/replaceState) to change the displayed URL on the `hashchange` event.

```html
<script>
window.addEventListener('hashchange', e => {
    history.replaceState({}, "", location.hash.slice(1));
});
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This small Javascript code should do the trick:

```js
window.addEventListener('hashchange', _ => {
    history.replaceState(null, "", location.href.replace('#', ''));
});
```

The event listener is called, when you click some of the `#` links and it will remove the `#` character in current URL. So from `https://example.com/#about` it will become  `https://example.com/about`.

**Note:** This will not work very well for URLs like `https://example.com/some-page#about`.

Comment: This solution works for the # but now if i click on other links it keeps on adding their name