# How to remove "#" from URLs in an Angular and .NET application

Tags: .net, angular, routes, single-page-application

I'm currently working on an Angular and .NET application that uses "#" in the URLs to indicate internal resources. However, I'm concerned about the impact this could have on our SEO, and I would like to remove "#" from our URLs if possible.

I'm looking for guidance on how to do this, as well as any potential drawbacks or compatibility issues that I should be aware of.

Here are some specific questions I have:

1. Is it possible to migrate an Angular and .NET application to remove the "#" symbol from the URLs?
2. What are the potential benefits and drawbacks of removing "#" from URLs in an Angular and .NET application?
3. What steps are required to remove "#" from URLs in an Angular and .NET application that uses GraphQL?
4. Are there any potential compatibility issues that could arise from removing "#" from URLs in an Angular and .NET application?

Any insights or advice would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance for your help!

I tried removing it but it crashes the website

Comment: This [may help](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53651553/2065039) or see if you have a `base-href` configured.

Comment: the `#` is because you force Angular to do it using [HasLocationStrategies](https://angular.io/guide/router#locationstrategy-and-browser-url-styles)

Comment: Routing can be set to use hashlocation or not.  Hashlocations won't require server-side redirects for handling Refresh button or bookmarks.  If you change the angular routing to not use hashlocation, you will want to test refresh button functionality and possibly add server-side redirects so that those URLs always load the single page.

Comment: You can check for this wherever routing module is configured... it'll be something like: RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { useHash: true })  Btw, the "#" is standard URL/HTML, and is used for bookmarks within a page.  This is why they are used in single-page-apps.  The browser does not attempt to do a page reload from the server.  The # indicates a bookmark within a page:  https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links_bookmarks.asp