# AngularJS how to alter incoming request URI

Tags: angularjs, url-routing

My AngularJS app uses the following URL pattern:

```
https://myapp/#!/mypage
```

But I now have to accept one incoming request from another app using this URI:

```
https://myapp/myotherpage
```

Note that the `/#!/` is missing from the incoming request.

How do I reformat the incoming request URI so that it becomes

```
https://myapp/#!/myotherpage
```

Answer (score 1):

You can follow the below code if you want to alter the URI using code

```
var incomingUrl ="https://myapp/myotherpage";
var uriPart=incomingUrl.split("myapp");
var actualUri=uriPart[0]+"myapp/#!"+uriPart[1]
console.log(actualUri);
```

You can use actualUri variable as a URL( it will be # converted url)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure, **where** the request to URL `https://myapp/myotherpage`  is incoming exactly.

If it is coming through until your AngularJS app, then you could modify your router-configuration as shown below.

Otherwise you need URL-rewriting or redirects on your server.

See also:
and similar question:
[AngularJS routing without the hash '#'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14319967/angularjs-routing-without-the-hash)

#### On the client-side

In AngularJS you could use HTML5 routing mode by setting

```js
app.config(function($routeProvider,$locationProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when('/myotherpage', {
        templateUrl:'/html/myotherpage.html'
    });

    $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
})
```

This will also remove the hash-bang (`#!`) as your app's internal route-prefix.

See details in documentation for [`locationProvider`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/provider/$locationProvider).

Comment: I don't want to remove the #! as this is wired into the app and a few other external modules. The incoming request is from Azure.