# what is the difference between ngSwitch and ngInclude?

Tags: angularjs

what is the difference between ngSwitch and ngInclude?

I really need to understand the difference, so I can continue on my project.

Does the ngSwitch hides only the dom elements?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You may find the v1.1.4 documentation more helpful (just ignore the stuff about animations if you are not using 1.1.4): [ngSwitch](http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.4/docs/api/ng.directive:ngSwitch)

`ngSwitch` conditionally adds/removes DOM elements (`ng-show/hide` alters CSS).

`ngInclude` can fetch partials/external HTML fragments.

Both create new child scopes that prototypically inherit from their parent scopes.  (A new child scope is created for each `ng-switch-when/default`.)

You can use `ngInclude` with `ngSwitch`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/12584774/215945

Use `ngInclude` when you want to (or can) reuse HTML fragments, such as client UI (https://stackoverflow.com/a/13005658/215945).

Comment: But the problem using NgInclude on my page is, I have 1000 elements on dataTables, and when I use ngInclude it freezes a litle while all elements are loading. I need something to hide/show

Comment: I have 5 different html pages, thats why I use ngInclude currently but its somehow not a good solution for my case. ngInclude makes the  dataTable reinitialize, so it freezes everytime I switch between the pages.